# Expanding a parent <div> to the height of its children

Tags: html, css

I have a page structure similar to this:

```
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="childRightCol">
      /*Content*/
    </div>
    <div id="childLeftCol">
      /*Content*/
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like for the parent `div` to expand in `height` when the inner `div`'s `height` increases.

**Edit:**
One problem is that if the `width` of the child content expands past the `width` of the browser window, my current CSS puts a horizontal scrollbar on the parent `div`.  I would like the scrollbar to be at the page level. Currently my parent div is set to `overflow: auto;`

Can you please help me with the CSS for this?

Comment: Are you floating the inner divs? Can you post the current CSS?

Comment: @Eric - it was my problem too - my child div(s) had float:left, when I removed it 'parent' was automatically recognized and stretched to full height!

Answer (score 620, accepted):

Try this for the parent, it worked for me.

```
overflow:auto;
```

**UPDATE:**

One more solution that worked:

**Parent**:

```
display: table;
```

**Child**:

```
display: table-row;
```

Comment: `overflow:auto` means that the browser should decide which value to apply. What really _does_ the trick is **`overflow: overlay`**.

Comment: @jmendeth An overflow-value called "overlay" does not exist. What is working if the child divs are floated is declaring `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Waaaait. Relax. One thing is claiming `overlay` isn't supported outside Webkit. Another completely different is to say it doesn't exist at all. Please, [RTFM first](http://help.dottoro.com/lcrmdnar.php). ;)

Comment: If it's only on Webkit then it only 20% exist :P Cheers for the link, never seen this website before. Is it well maintained and updated? Do you swear by it?

Comment: An alternative answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents and it proposes to set `display:inline-block`.  Which worked great for me.

Answer (score 72):

Try to give `max-content`for parent's height.

```css
.parent{
  height: max-content;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/FreeS/so4L83wu/5/

Comment: How does that property behaves with other browsers?

On MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#Browser_compatibility

Comment: This seemed to be the only thing that fixed the problem in Safari 12.

Comment: Does this work to the container of an iframe? Interested for a friend.

Answer (score 27):

add a `clear:both`.  assuming that your columns are floating.  Depending on how your height is specified parent you may need an overflow:auto;

```
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="childRightCol">
    <div>
    <div id="childLeftCol">
    <div>
    <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Doing this gives me a horizontal scrollbar on the parent div when the content is wider than the browser window.  I would like the horizontal scroll to be on the whole page.

Comment: Why do you need the overflow:auto;? In my test the clear:both; sufficed.

Comment: This also assuming that the parent doesn't have a height specified.

Comment: This approach works fine in Firefox, but doesn't work in IE 6.  Any workarounds?

Comment: this work fine in Chrome but not in Safari :(, any other suggestion please that work in Safari

Answer (score 19):

As Jens said in comment

> An alternative answer is [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/)… and it
>   proposes to set display:inline-block. Which worked great for me. –
>   Jens Jun 2 at 5:41

This works far better for me in all browsers.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of setting height property, use min-height.

Comment: you are a champion, this fixed the issue i was struggling with in IE :)))

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
clear:both;
```

To the css of the parent div, or add a div at the bottom of the parent div that does clear:both;

That is the correct answer, because overflow:auto; may work for simple web layouts, but will mess with elements that start using things like negative margin, etc

Comment: Adding div at the bottom of the parent with no content and clear:both solved the problem for me. All other solutions have failes. And I agree, this should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

For those who can not figure out this in instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384145/css-expand-parent-div-to-child-height/384170#384170) there:

Try to set **padding** value **more** then **0**, if child divs have margin-top or margin-bottom you can replace it with padding

For example if you have

```
#childRightCol
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#childLeftCol
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

it'll be better to replace it with:

```
#parent
{
    padding: 30px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using something like self-clearing `div` is perfect for a situation like [this](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html). Then you'll just use a class on the parent... like:

```
<div id="parent" class="clearfix">
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code worked for me.

## css

```
.parent{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

## html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
    </div>
    <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `height: auto` or using `min-height` on parent element will work. And for avoiding horizontal scrollbar, which can be caused due to padding or border can be avoided by using `box-sizing: border-box` on child element or `overflow: hidden` on parent element.
As for horizontal scrollbar caused due to width of body, in case you are using `width: 100vw` instead use `width:100%`.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
.childRightCol, .childLeftCol
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Where We’re Starting From**

Here’s some boilerplate HTML and CSS. In our example, we have a parent element with two floated child elements.

```css
/* The CSS you're starting with may look similar to this.
 * This doesn't solve our problem yet, but we'll get there shortly.
 */

.containing-div {
  background-color: #d2b48c;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.floating-div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.floating-div ul {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- The HTML you're starting with might look similar to this -->
<div class="containing-div">
  <div class="floating-div">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item One</li>
      <li>List Item Two</li>
      <li>List Item Three</li>
      <li>List Item Four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="floating-div">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item Five</li>
      <li>List Item Six</li>
      <li>List Item Seven</li>
      <li>List Item Eight</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution #1: overflow: auto**

A solution that works in all modern browsers and in Internet Explorer back to IE8 is to add `overflow: auto` to the parent element. This also works in IE7, with scrollbars added.

```css
/* Our Modified CSS.
 * This is one way we can solve our problem.
 */

.containing-div {
  background-color: #d2b48c;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  /*This is what we added!*/
}

.floating-div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.floating-div ul {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}
```

**Solution #2: Float Parent Container**

Another solution that works in all modern browsers and back to IE7 is to float the parent container.

This may not always be practical, because floating your parent div may affect other parts of your page layout.

```css
/* Modified CSS #2.
 * Floating parent div.
 */

.containing-div {
  background-color: #d2b48c;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  /*Added*/
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*Added*/
}

.floating-div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.floating-div ul {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}
```

**Method #3: Add Clearing Div Below Floated Elements**

```css
/* 
 * CSS to Solution #3.
 */

.containing-div {
  background-color: #d2b48c;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.floating-div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.floating-div ul {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}


/*Added*/

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!-- Solution 3, Add a clearing div to bottom of parent element -->
<div class="containing-div">
  <div class="floating-div">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item One</li>
      <li>List Item Two</li>
      <li>List Item Three</li>
      <li>List Item Four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="floating-div">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item Five</li>
      <li>List Item Six</li>
      <li>List Item Seven</li>
      <li>List Item Eight</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**Method #4: Add Clearing Div To The Parent Element**
This solution is pretty bulletproof for older browsers and newer browsers alike.

```css
/* 
 * CSS to Solution #4.
 */

.containing-div {
  background-color: #d2b48c;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.floating-div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.floating-div ul {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}


/*Added*/

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!-- Solution 4, make parent element self-clearing -->
<div class="containing-div clearfix">
  <div class="floating-div">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item One</li>
      <li>List Item Two</li>
      <li>List Item Three</li>
      <li>List Item Four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="floating-div">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item Five</li>
      <li>List Item Six</li>
      <li>List Item Seven</li>
      <li>List Item Eight</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

from https://www.lockedownseo.com/parent-div-100-height-child-floated-elements/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a [2 column CSS layout](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/finished.html)?

If so, have a look at [the instructions](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/), it's pretty straightforward for starting.

Answer (score 1):

I made a parent div expand around content of a child div by having the child div as a single column that does not have any positioning attribute such as absolute  specified.

Example:

```
#wrap {width:400px;padding:10px 200px 10px 200px;position:relative;margin:0px auto;}
#maincolumn {width:400px;}
```

Based on maincolumn div being the deepest child div of #wrap this defines the depth of the #wrap div and the 200px padding on either side creates two big blank columns for you to place absolutely positioned divs in as you please. You could even change the padding top and bottom to place header divs and footer divs using position:absolute.

Answer (score 1):

If your content inside #childRightCol and #childRightCol are floated left or right, just add this into css:

```
#childRightCol:before { display: table; content: " "; }
#childRightCol:after { display: table; content: " "; clear: both; }
#childLeftCol:before { display: table; content: " "; }
#childLeftCol:after { display: table; content: " "; clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the clearfix solution on the parent container. Here is a nice article explaining the fix [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Answer (score 0):

This is functioning as described by the spec - several answers here are valid, and consistent with the following:

> If it has block-level children, the height is the distance between the top border-edge of the topmost block-level child box that doesn't have margins collapsed through it and the bottom border-edge of the bottommost block-level child box that doesn't have margins collapsed through it. However, if the element has a nonzero top padding and/or top border, or is the root element, then the content starts at the top margin edge of the topmost child. (The first case expresses the fact that the top and bottom margins of the element collapse with those of the topmost and bottommost children, while in the second case the presence of the padding/border prevents the top margins from collapsing.) Similarly, if the element has a nonzero bottom padding and/or bottom border, then the content ends at the bottom margin edge of the bottommost child.

from here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#blockwidth

Answer (score 0):

```css
#childRightCol
{
float:right;
}
#childLeftCol
{
float:left;
}
#parent
{
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this CSS to parent and it works:

```
min-height:350px;
background:url(../images/inner/details_middle.gif) repeat-y 0 0 ;
padding:5px 10px;   
text-align:right;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: You use min-height, so doesn't count ;)

Answer (score -1):

```css
#parent{
  background-color:green;
  height:auto;
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#childRightCol{
  color:gray;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="childRightCol">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vulputate sit amet neque ac consequat.
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

you are manage by using `overflow:hidden;` property in css