# How can I make a div not larger than its contents?

Tags: html, css, width

I have a layout similar to:

```
<div>
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would like for the `div` to only expand to as wide as my `table` becomes.

Comment: the effect is called "shrinkwrapping", and as answered there's a couple of ways to do this (float, inline, min/max-width) all of which have side-effects to choose from

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I didn't find anything wrong with how the question was answered.

Comment: Impossible, in reality. Languages, fonts, Unicode characters with different width, pixelDeviceRatio, browsers versions, etc, etc, (...),  CSS is a loss of time because it's just not smart enough to handle all that.

Answer (score 2822):

The solution is to set your `div` to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @leif81 You can use a `span` or a `div` or `ul` or anything else, the important part is for the container you would like to be minimum width have the CSS property `display: inline-block`

Comment: Please make note that once you have `display: inline-block` property set the `margin: 0 auto;` won't work as expected. In that case if the parent container has `text-align: center;` then the `inline-block` element will be horizontally centered.

Comment: Adding to @SavasVedova comment, remember to change `auto` in  `margin: 0 auto;` to `0` (or whatever value you may choose).

Comment: This is not a solution if we want our element to have another display property, like grid, for instance. [@Vitalii Fedorenko's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16765030/10254049) uses a newer `fit-content` property, which works for any display property, doesn't add margin, and [is supported on all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content#browser_compatibility).

Comment: This would be great if I wanted my components to flow inline XD. `fit-content` seems to be the modern solution.

Comment: This has the side effect that your div is now inline rather than on a line of its own. Use `display: block` in combination with `width: max-content` or `width: fit-content` to have it on a line of its own but still have the width not larger than its contents. The difference between the two options, I don't understand to be honest; either one sounds fine to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704073/what-is-the-difference-between-css-fit-content-and-max-content

Answer (score 368):

You want a block element that has what CSS calls shrink-to-fit width and the spec does not provide a blessed way to get such a thing. In CSS2, shrink-to-fit is not a goal, but means to deal with a situation where browser "has to" get a width out of thin air. Those situations are:

- float
- absolutely positioned element
- inline-block element
- table element

when there are no width specified. I heard they think of adding what you want in CSS3. For now, make do with one of the above.

The decision not to expose the feature directly may seem strange, but there is a good reason. It is expensive. Shrink-to-fit means formatting at least twice: you cannot start formatting an element until you know its width, and you cannot calculate the width w/o going through entire content. Plus, one does not need shrink-to-fit element as often as one may think. Why do you need extra div around your table? Maybe table caption is all you need.

Comment: I would say `inline-block` is exactly intended for this and solves the problem perfectly.

Comment: @miahelf – Famous last words, at no point was inline-block the perfect way for this, and never will it be considered as such.

Answer (score 266):

I think using

```css
display: inline-block;
```

would work, however I'm not sure about the browser compatibility.

---

Another solution would be to wrap your `div` in another `div` (if you want to maintain the block behavior):

HTML:

```html
<div>
    <div class="yourdiv">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.yourdiv
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: To answer the browser compatibility question: this won't work with IE7/8 on DIV elements.  You have to use SPAN elements.

Comment: The link at https://caniuse.com/?search=inline-block says that 99% of browsers support the unprefixed version, which is (when you toggle date-relative) browsers since 2008. (That's more than ES5's support!)

Answer (score 255):

You can try [`fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) (CSS3):

```css
div {
  width: fit-content; 
  /* To adjust the height as well */ 
  height: fit-content;
}
```

- [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width)
- [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#fit-content)

Comment: This makes too much sense, of course it lacks support.

Comment: This together with `margin: auto` is what I went with.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Perfect. It will never get widespread use.

Comment: To save everyone a caniuse lookup: it is now widely supported. Sorry for crashing the joke thread above, I do appreciate the humor that "this makes sense -> it will never become supported" :)

Answer (score 251):

`display: inline-block` adds an extra margin to your element.

I would recommend this:

```css
#element {
    display: table; /* IE8+ and all other modern browsers */
}
```

**Bonus:** You can also now easily center that fancy new `#element` just by adding `margin: 0 auto`.

Answer (score 106):

There are two better solutions

1. `display: inline-block;`

   OR
2. `display: table;`

**Out of these two `display:table;` is better,** because `display: inline-block;` adds an extra margin.

For `display:inline-block;` you can use the negative margin method to fix the extra space

Answer (score 91):

What works for me is:

```
display: table;
```

in the `div`. (Tested on **Firefox** and **Google Chrome**).

Answer (score 85):

```css
display: -moz-inline-stack;
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

[Foo Hack – Cross Browser Support for inline-block Styling (2007-11-19)](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/).

Answer (score 49):

Not knowing in what context this will appear, but I believe the CSS-style property `float` either `left` or `right` will have this effect. On the other hand, it'll have other side effects as well, such as allowing text to float around it.

Please correct me if I'm wrong though, I'm not 100% sure, and currently can't test it myself.

Answer (score 45):

The answer for your question lays in the future my friend ...

namely "intrinsic" is coming with the latest CSS3 update

```css
width: intrinsic;
```

unfortunately **IE** is behind with it so it doesn't support it yet

More about it: [CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/) and [*Can I Use?*: Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing](http://caniuse.com/intrinsic-width).

For now you have to be satisfied with `<span>` or `<div>` set to

```css
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: How do intrinsic and fit-content differ?

Answer (score 40):

A CSS2 compatible solution is to use:

```css
.my-div
{
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

You can also float your div which will force it as small as possible, but you'll need to use a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) if anything inside your div is floating:

```css
.my-div
{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 40):

```css
width:1px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

works fine for me :)

Answer (score 34):

This has been mentioned in comments and is hard to find in one of the answers so:

If you are using `display: flex` for whatever reason, you can instead use:

```css
div {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

[This is also widely supported across browsers.](https://caniuse.com/#search=inline-flex)

Comment: Finally a `caniuse` reference!

Answer (score 31):

Just put a style into your CSS file

```css
div { 
    width: fit-content; 
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about why SO allows so many almost-duplicate answers.

Answer (score 30):

**OK,** in many cases you even don't need to do anything as by default div has `height` and `width` as auto, but if it's not your case, applying `inline-block` display gonna work for you... look at the code I create for you and it's do what you looking for:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ultrices feugiat massa sed laoreet. Maecenas et magna egestas, facilisis purus quis, vestibulum nibh.</td>
      <td>Nunc auctor aliquam est ac viverra. Sed enim nisi, feugiat sed accumsan eu, convallis eget felis. Pellentesque consequat eu leo nec pharetra. Aenean interdum enim dapibus diam.</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ultrices feugiat massa sed laoreet. Maecenas et magna egestas, facilisis purus quis, vestibulum nibh.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

just set the width and height to fit-content. it is very simple.

```css
div {

    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

> I am adding **padding: 10px;**. if it is left out, the div element will completely stick with the table and it will look a bit clumsy. Padding will create the given space between the border of the element and it's contents. But it is your wish not compulsory.

Comment: Other than the `adding: 10px;` part, this is the same answer that was posted on May 27 '13 at 0:41

Comment: width:"fit-content",

Answer (score 28):

You can try this code. Follow the code in the CSS section.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2vw;
  background-color: green;
}

table {
  width: 70vw;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table border="colapsed">
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td>Strawberry</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td>Strawberry</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td>Strawberry</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

Try to use `width: max-content` property to adjust the width of the div by it's content size.

Try this example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.ex1 {
  width:500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

div.ex2 {
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ex1">This div element has width 500px;</div>
<br>
<div class="ex2">Width by content size</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="content_lalala">
                this content inside the div being inside a table, needs no inline properties and the table is the one expanding to the content of this div =)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know people don't like tables sometimes, but I gotta tell you, I tried the css inline hacks, and they kinda worked in some divs but in others didn't, so, it was really just easier to enclose the expanding div in a table...and...it can have or not the inline property and still the table is the one that's gonna hold the total width of the content. =)

Answer (score 20):

You can do it simply by using `display: inline;` (or `white-space: nowrap;`).

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `inline-block` as @user473598, but beware of older browsers..

```
/* Your're working with */
display: inline-block;

/* For IE 7 */
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;

/* For Mozilla Firefox < 3.0 */
display:-moz-inline-stack;
```

Mozilla doesn’t support inline-block at all, but they have `-moz-inline-stack` which is about the same

Some cross-browser around `inline-block` display attribute:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/

You can see some tests with this attribute in: https://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Answer (score 16):

An working demo is here-

```css
.floating-box {
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;

    width: fit-content; 
    height: fit-content;

    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
```

```html
<h2>The Way is using inline-block</h2>

Supporting elements are also added in CSS.

<div>
   <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
   <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

My CSS3 flexbox solution in two flavors: The one on top behaves like a span and the one at the bottom behaves like a div, taking all the width with the help of a wrapper. Their classes are "top", "bottom" and "bottomwrapper" respectively.

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.top {
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.top, .bottom {
    background-color: #3F3;
    border: 2px solid #FA6;
}
/* bottomwrapper will take the rest of the width */
.bottomwrapper {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
    width: 280px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
th {
    background-color: #282;
    color: #FFF;
}
td {
    color: #444;
}
th, td {
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
```

```html
Is this
<div class="top">
 <table>
        <tr>
            <th>OS</th>
            <th>Version</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>OpenBSD</td>
            <td>5.7</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Windows</td>
            <td>Please upgrade to 10!</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
what you are looking for?
<br>
Or may be...
<div class="bottomwrapper">
    <div class="bottom">
     <table>
            <tr>
                <th>OS</th>
                <th>Version</th> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>OpenBSD</td>
                <td>5.7</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Windows</td>
                <td>Please upgrade to 10!</td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
this is what you are looking for.
```

Comment: kudos for `display: inline-flex;`. BTW this works without prefix for Chrome 62, firefox 57, and safari 11

Answer (score 11):

Tampering around with Firebug I found the property value `-moz-fit-content` which exactly does what the OP wanted and could be used as follow:

```
width: -moz-fit-content;
```

Although it only works on Firefox, I couldn't find any equivalent for other browsers such as Chrome.

Comment: As of January 2017, IE (all versions, Edge and mobile included) and Opera Mini have no support for `fit-content`. Firefox supports width only. Other browsers support it well.

Answer (score 11):

```
<div class="parentDiv" style="display:inline-block">
    // HTML elements
</div>
```

This will make parent div width same as the largest element width.

Comment: is there a way i can apply this only for vertical size to minimize and keep horizontal large?

Answer (score 11):

Try `display: inline-block;`. For it to be cross browser compatible please use the below css code.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  display:-moz-inline-stack;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Column1</td>
      <td>Column2</td>
      <td>Column3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

```css
div{
width:fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Has to be ``width: -moz-fit-content;`` to work on Firefox.

Answer (score 10):

```
    .outer{
          width:fit-content;   
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
    }
    .outer .content{
         width: 100%;
    }
        
        
        
        
<div class=outer>
    <div class=content>
       Add your content here


    </div>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I have solved a similar problem (where I didn't want to use `display: inline-block` because the item was centered) by adding a `span` tag inside the `div` tag, and moving the CSS formatting from the outer `div` tag to the new inner `span` tag. Just throwing this out there as another alternative idea if `display: inline block` isn't a suitable answer for you.

Answer (score 7):

We can use any of the two ways on the **`div`** element:

```
display: table;
```

or,

```
display: inline-block;
```

I prefer to use `display: table;`, because it handles, all extra spaces on its own. While `display: inline-block` needs some extra space fixing.

Answer (score 6):

```
div{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if div contains inline (or inline-block) elements and they have different font-size and line-height than the div itself.

Answer (score 5):

Revised (works if you have multiple children):
You can use jQuery (Look at the JSFiddle link)

```
var d= $('div');
var w;


d.children().each(function(){
 w = w + $(this).outerWidth();
 d.css('width', w + 'px')
});
```

Do not forget to include the jQuery...

[See the JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wyx2mnyy/)

Comment: This is broken if your div has multiple children; it simply sets the div width to that of the *first* child.

Comment: @MarkAmery First of all, before you give it a negative vote, please read the question carefully, they asked for one child. If you are really curious how it can be done with multiple children see the revised answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you have containers breaking lines, after hours looking for a good CSS solution and finding none, [I now use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511762/274502) jQuery instead:

```js
$('button').click(function(){

  $('nav ul').each(function(){
    
    $parent = $(this).parent();
    
    $parent.width( $(this).width() );
    
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left; /* doesn't do anything, unlike some might guess */
}
ul {
  display: inline;
}

/* needed style */
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 420px;
}

/* just style */
body {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
button {
  display: block;
}
nav {
  background: #bbb;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid thin #777;
  margin: 4px;
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>fix</button>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is visibly broken in the snippet for me in Chrome; clicking the fix button a second time produces different results to clicking it the first time.

Comment: @MarkAmery on my mac I just tried it on chrome, safari and firefox and it's all fine: no visible errors, nothing on the console, consistent behavior. maybe it's something with windows...

Answer (score 4):

I tried `div.classname{display:table-cell;}` and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `display: flex` for parent element

```
#parentElement {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: flex-start;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just set `padding: -whateverYouWantpx;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: It would take away some size of the box so he could make the box "not larger than its contents."

Comment: Isn't negative padding invalid CSS?

Comment: Far from it.  In fact I've used it many times and it's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3):

I've a `span` inside a `div` and just setting `margin: auto` to the container `div` worked for me.

Comment: Any clue why this works?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set your **.table-badge** class to **display: inline-block**

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, I simply do this :

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
div {
    display: inline;
}
```

If you apply a float on your div, it works too but obviously, you need to apply a "clear both" CSS rules at the next HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
<div style="display: inline;">
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What if we define a global variable and use that for both.

```css
:root {
    --table-width: 400px;
}

.container{
     width:var(--table-width);
     border: 1px solid black;   // easy visualization
}
.inner-table {
     width:var(--table-width);
     border: 1px solid red;   // easy visualization
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="inner-table">
       <tr>
           <td>abc</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Seems it's a 13 years old question.

```
.div{
display:inline-block;
}
```

or

```
.div{
display:inline-flex;
}
```

would work now a days without any compatibility issues.

Answer (score -4):

This seems to work fine for me on all browsers. Example is an actual ad i use online and in newsletter. Just change the content of the div. It will adjust and shrinkwrap with the amount of padding you specify.

```
<div style="float:left; border: 3px ridge red; background: aqua; padding:12px">
    <font color=red size=4>Need to fix a birth certificate? Learn <a href="http://www.example.com">Photoshop in a Day</a>!
    </font>
</div>
```

Comment: font is utterly deprecated. probably renders as <span> on any current engine.

Comment: @zanlok He's talking about a newsletter, `<font>` still seems to be fair game  in email land despite its deprecation (2nd answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012799/do-we-still-need-to-use-font-tags-in-html-emails

Answer (score -5):

You can use `height: 100%` and width for your choice. This makes the div not larger than its content.

Comment: if u set height 100% it will be 100% of the window total size