# Need generic div css that does not overlap (like a table)

Tags: html, css, overlap, css-tables

I'm trying to use divs instead of tables to style boxes around my content.  The content can be **any size** and needs to allow the browser to be **resized to any degree**.  Need the background color and border to **contain the content**.  This works fine with tables.  How do I get a div to work the same way?

Note: I added "_"s because my non-breaking spaces were getting lost.

[Sample Page](http://www.c3o.com/divonly.htm)

[Sample image](http://www.c3o.com/div-like-table.JPG)

[image]
<sub>(source: [c3o.com](http://www.c3o.com/div-like-table.JPG))</sub>

Content:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.box, table.box
    {
        padding: 10px 1000px 10px 10px;
    }

    div.box-header, td.box-header
    {
        border:  solid  1px  #BBBBBB ;
        font-size: larger;
        padding: 4px;
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
    }   

    div.box-body, td.box-body
    {
        padding: 6px;
        border:  solid  1px  #BBBBBB ;
        border-top: none;
    }
</style>


<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">please_help_make_these_divs_stop_overlapping</div>
    <div class="box-body">please_help_make_these_divs_stop_overlapping</div>
</div>

<table class="box" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td class="box-header">tables_make_good_containers_tables_make_good</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="box-body">tables_make_good_containers_tables_make_good</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can not see them overlapping they work the same way, what's the problem here?

Comment: I don't see any issues. IE6 and FF2 both show the same behavior -- it's working correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I keep trying to upload my image...does not seem to be making it.  Take a look at:  

http://www.c3o.com/div-like-table.JPG

Comment: Resize your browser way down (IE or Firefox) the table contains but divs do not.

Comment: I increased the padding to 1000 so you can easily see overlap

Comment: The links are now dead making the question unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this that is crossbrowser friendly that I know of.

At least in firefox you can create an simulated table by setting divs with

```
display:table;
display:table-row;
display:table-cell;
```

So that those divs work like table elements. Then the box will contain it's content. Wether that's a good solution or not is debateable.

I've been having similar issues with page layouts myself. Usually I've solved those by setting min-width and overflow:auto;

Comment: I wish there was an overflow:contain; in css.

Comment: Thanks.  overflow:contain is exactly what I need.  Then I can stop using tables.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such value as overflow: contain
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: There is no such value, that's why I said that I wish there was.

Comment: display:table is not a realistic option until it is supported by IE

Comment: Rory, you're correct. That's why my first sentence said that there's no easy crossbrowser way

Comment: "Then I can stop using tables" being some time in the future...:)

Comment: Looks like you were correct from the start.  "There is no easy way to do this".  I'm going back to tables for this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want to use a table you can do this:

```
div.box div {
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1; /* trigger haslayout for ie */
}
```

Next time this kind of problem comes up go to [giveupandusetables.com](http://giveupandusetables.com/).

Comment: Nice link.  I am surprised how hard this has been.  Seems like such a basic thing: "a container that always contains content".

Comment: my answer is giveupandusetables.com

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make your boxes floats. Add float:left; to box, box-header, and box-body. Add clear:both; to box-body to force it below box-header. You'll probably need to add clear property to whatever content follows as well.

You will not get right edges of box-header and box-body to align, though. If you want their widths to be the same, you really want a table. Table is a tool to make all cells in the same column to share the widths.

For other ideas, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents/451074#451074).

Comment: Thanks.  I want the widths to be the same.  Sounds like I need to use tables.

Answer (score 0):

This works (actually holds together better than tables in ie7 too)

```
div.box{
  float:left;
  width:auto;
  margin: 10px 1000px 10px 10px;
}

div.box-header{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  border:  solid  1px  #BBBBBB ;
  font-size: larger;
  padding: 4px; 
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

div.box-body{
  clear:left;
  float:left;
  width:100%; 
  padding: 4px; 
  border:  solid  1px  #BBBBBB ; 
  border-top: none;
}
```

NOTE: both boxes have to have same left and right padding or one juts out a bit.

Comment: I tested it in Firefox and it was fine for me

Comment: Just tested again, this time in chrome and safari too. You sure you copied the code correctly? coz it definitely does work.

Comment: The container should not overlap AND resize with the page.  When I pull it up in firefox you solved the overlap but no resize.  I put up a sample here: http://www.c3o.com/wheresrhys.htm

Comment: Well that's just plain weird. Here is a test page I've done which works: http://wheresrhys.co.uk/resources/test.html. There must be some tiny unspottable difference between what we've got.

Comment: I think your doc type is telling firefox to use quirks mode which makes it work.  Is quirks mode bad?  I'll change my doc type and see if I can get this to work in real life.

Comment: Good point. I've now amended the doctype...
... and it still works.
I've noticed one major differehce with your copy though: you have margin 10px on all sides of the box, whereas I have 1000px on one side

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be using semantic markup. If something is a header and content mark it up as such with header and paragraph tags. That will help you move out of the 'table-way' of thinking were you try to emulate your markup and styles like a table, markup should come first, CSS can come after.

The following should do what you want:

```
<style type="text/css">
    * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
.box {
border: solid 1px #BBBBBB;
margin:10px;
}
.box h3 {
padding: 4px;
border-bottom: solid 1px #BBBBBB;
background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
.box p {
padding: 6px;
}
</style>

<div class='box'>
    <h3>please help make these divs stop overlapping</h3>
    <p>please help make these divs stop overlapping</p>
</div>
```

Thinking about markup and style separately is the path to CSS Zen Mastery :o)

Comment: Thanks but this still allows overlaps.  Nice but misses the point of the question.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'overlaps' then, this worked fine for me in FF3.

Comment: I added some non-breaking spaces to make it more obvious.  Check out this image of firefox:  http://www.c3o.com/overlap1.jpg.  I just need a container that will not overlap (like a table).

Answer (score 0):

Floats are not needed, but you seem to be confusing the uses of margin vs. padding. The following minor tweaks to your style works as you need it to:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.box, table.box
    {
        margin: 10px 1000px 10px 10px;
        border:  solid  1px  #BBBBBB ;
       padding: 0px;
    }

    div.box-header, td.box-header
    {

        font-size: larger;
        padding: 4px;
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom:  solid  1px  #BBBBBB ;

    }   

    .box-body, td.box-body
    {
        padding: 6px;
    }
</style>
```

I've changed the padding on the box to a margin, moved the border to your box, and added an underline to the header.

Comment: I probably am mixing up padding and margins but you solution still has the same overlap.  Just run it with a non-quirks mode doc-type.

Comment: I misunderstood the problem. I'll look at again later - only have IE at work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also using Firefox 6.0.1, Opera 10.62, Safari 5.1, but not in IE 9, and the overflow:auto fixed it in all browsers. Nothing else did. I also tried overflow:contain, which also fixed the problem, but it appears that contain is not a valid value for overflow, so I am assuming that, since the value was not valid, auto was substituted.