# div border not surrounding content

Tags: css, html, border

HI 
 i want to give my div's some border but when i do a box is created with all the borders but the contents of teh div are not surrounded!! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try

```
 overflow: auto
```

Comment: This will add scrollbars on overflow. If you (like I) were looking for how to get the div to extend (shrinkwrap) to its contents size, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents

Answer (score 1):

You must have some floating content inside.

```
<div id="divWithBorderIssue">
   blah
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

You could also use a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

edit: of course if you provided the code it would be easier to help you