# Css header problem

Tags: css

I have a header class which has a background and a header-center class which provides the nav content for the header. My problem is that if the window is smaller than the header-center width, the header background doesn't span the entire top when you scroll over. Stackoverflow seems to have the same problem, try resizing it and you'll see what I mean - they gray background doesn't expand over to the search box. How would I go about fixing this?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see what you mean in regards to SO's header by the way - I get a grey background all the way

Comment: i think he means this: http://grab.by/6Wr2

Answer (score 0):

if the background is inside a container with a width of 100% and any parent container, including the `<body>` or `<html>` don't have a width set in the CSS then you will experience this behaviour. as 100% will be 100% of the browser viewport. Change this to a fixed width and it should stretch to fill the fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set a `display: inline-block` on your body tag.  If you do this to stack-overflow's site.  It fixes the problem.

This method is called "shrink-to-fit".

Here's a fiddle with the problem. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NWvQ7/1/)
As you can see when you scroll the div doesn't expand the width of the whole screen anymore.

and here's a fiddle without the problem. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6VNAv/)

This has been answered similarly elsewhere by user473598 here [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents) you don't technically need the element to be a span though. buti-oxa's answer is worth noting as well as it notes that using this method is some what costly as it means formatting the element at least twice.  Since it's being applied to the body it doesn't seem like that bad of a deal in your situation.