# Horizontal scrolling with overflow-x

Tags: jquery, css, image, scrollbar, overflow

I was wondering if there still isn't a good way to get a `div` to stretch and scroll horizontally, according to the images inside. After all, it is 2011 now!

The `mega-width` does the trick, but leaves an empty `mega-space` if not filled with images.
If filled too much, images don't display. Same for the jQuery.
The situation below is the best I can do after hours of Googling, but it isn't reliable enough.

Thanks for your time.

---

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#one {
  width: 200px;    
  height: 250px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#two {
  width: 10000em;
}

#two img {
  float: left;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".calc").each(function() {
    total += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $("#two").css('width', total);
  alert(total);
});
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <img src="images/testimage3.jpg" width="480" height="192" class="calc">
    <img src="images/testimage3.jpg" width="480" height="192" class="calc">
    <img src="images/testimage3.jpg" width="480" height="192" class="calc">
    <img src="images/testimage3.jpg" width="480" height="192" class="calc">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's easy. `display:inline-block` on the images and `white-space:nowrap` on the parent.

**Edit:** I forgot that images are by default inline, anyway :) That means that `white-space:nowrap` is all you need.

```css
div { 
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/U4RsQ/2/

Comment: @Starx I don't have older versions of IE, but according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets%29 IE6 supports white-space:nowrap. I don't know about overflow-x and overflow-y, thou (in IE6, that is).

Comment: Your first example was enough to get me to smile.

Comment: As long as you know the quirks with the IE6 box model, you'll be fine. If not, IE6's hasLayout only works when set to visible and with a height of 1%.
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout

Comment: @SIME : how would you adapt this for the image to display on more than one line ?

Comment: @MarcelFalliere Do you mean two (or more) rows of images?

Comment: @SIME yes ; I achieved it with css3 multi-column http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

Answer (score 0):

See [Make CSS Div Width Equal To Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents), I think, for stretching.  Then apply a `max-width` to constrain width to not be super-huge.  (And `overflow: scroll` if necessary.)

Comment: Thanks all, i looooove stackoverflow so much

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me with IE8:

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can ensure your page displays with the latest rendering by including the following meta tag in your page's head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```