# How can I adjust DIV width to contents

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a div element with style attached:

```
.mypost {
    border: 1px solid Peru;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 700px;
    width: 700px;
}
```

I am diplaying WordPress post contents inside the DIV block but for simplicity let assume that there is only one `<img>` inside the DIV. I want my div to be minimum 700 px wide and adjust the width if image is wider than 700 px.

What are my options to achieve that? Please advice.

***UPDATE***

See my Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cpt_comic/4qjXv/

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-can-i-make-a-div-not-larger-than-its-contents

Answer (score 95):

One way you can achieve this is setting `display: inline-block;` on the `div`. It is by default a `block` element, which will always fill the width it can fill (unless specifying `width` of course).

`inline-block`'s only downside is that IE only supports it correctly from version 8. IE 6-7 only allows setting it on naturally `inline` elements, but there are [hacks to solve this problem](http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/).

There are other options you have, you can either `float` it, or set `position: absolute` on it, but these also have other effects on layout, you need to decide which one fits your situation better.

- [`inline-block` jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/jMNwB/)

Comment: why wrong answer, you used width to reduce size in jsFiddle demo

Comment: @Adeem Reread the question please. The inner div has a fixed width, and the outer div should be adjusted to the width of its contents, **but** should also have a `min-width`. My fiddle shows the state when the `min-width` is doing its job. Please experiment with the fiddle and see it is working (pro tip: increase the width of the inner element to `300px` and see what happens).

Answer (score 39):

I'd like to add to the other answers this pretty new solution:

If you don't want the element to become inline-block, you can do this:

```
.parent{
  width: min-content;
}
```

The support is increasing fast, so when edge decides to implement it, it will be really great: http://caniuse.com/#search=intrinsic

Comment: That is brilliant!

Comment: I had to modify a little to fit what I was needing; "width: max-content; max-width: 100%"

Answer (score 17):

You could try using `float:left;` or `display:inline-block;`.

Both of these will change the element's behaviour from defaulting to 100% width to defaulting to the natural width of its contents.

However, note that they'll also both have an impact on the layout of the surrounding elements as well. I would suggest that `inline-block` will have less of an impact though, so probably best to try that first.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2- Yea auto fills the DOM SOZ!

```
#img_box{        
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

check out this fiddle

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/4qjXv/2/</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/4qjXv/3/

and this page

http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3828593.htm

Removed original answer because it was wrong.

The width is ok- but the height resets to 0

so

```
 min-height: 400px;
```

Comment: This won't work. `width: auto` will make the div fill up the whole space.

Comment: Thanks but it does not keep minimum width. Remove the image and see.