# how to make a div's width a certain x px but also make it expandable?

Tags: css, html

I have a box that has the div class `box_1` assigned to it.

Now i want to give this class a width but also make it expandable.

If i just try to give it a value of auto, It will just expand to the end of the screen. thats not what i want. So say i give it a width of 4 inches but the content inside the div requires more space (dynamic content), it will need to be expanded. any ideas on how i could make it expandable (only when it needs to be expanded) and also give it a 'default width'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS propety `min-width` for this.

You can do it like this:

```
.box_1{
    min-width: 4in;
}
```

Now the div would take up 4 inches by default if the content fits within it, and expand if needed.

**Update :**
Looking around i found this [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents)

So what you need is to use following css:

```
.box_1{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 4in;
}
```

This sets the minimum width to a specific amount and converts the element to `inline-block`. But as per the post linked above this does not work in IE 7/8, for that you would need to change the `div` to `span`.

Try it out here:
`div` => http://jsfiddle.net/TdNHs/
`span` => http://jsfiddle.net/TdNHs/1/

Comment: that wont work. the min-width just stops it from getting smaller then x px. I need something that will give it a default width but make it expandable if needed. thanks

Comment: @Nav can you use javascript for this, or do you need a pure CSS solution ?

Comment: @Nav I have updated my answer, have a look. It is done in pure CSS, but as the `min-height` property is not available in IE6 the effect is not complete there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .box_1{
        min-width: 0px !important;
       }
```

it will get the small as possible and also expandable

ti will be at 0px, but.. hey, what's your default width anyway?

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/tbUUt/1/

I just used the content inside te expandable div some boxes, but you can remove them one by one and the div will resize.

```
#box_1{
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: inline-block;

       }

<div id="box_1">

    <div style="border:1px solid blue; width: 50px; height:50px;float:left;"></div>
     <div style="border:1px solid blue; width: 50px; height:50px;float:left;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue; width: 50px; height:50px;float:left;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue; width: 50px; height:50px;float:left;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid blue; width: 50px; height:50px;float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, thats not what it does. it simply stops it getting any smaller then the given value. It will not give a default.

Comment: well, this is confusing.. you want a div with default width of 50px for ex but also you want it expandable, right?

Comment: I am working on it, I'll let you know on a few minutes if I have solution, or may be by that time there will be one from another guy.