# Do we still need to use <font> tags in HTML emails?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm taking over from someone who builds our HTML emails and the templates are filled with font tags. Is this really necessary? I know CSS support isn't great in emails, but if I set an inline style for text on the container `<td>` like this...

```
<td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica;color:#555555;font-size:12px">
```

...then surely this will work across the majority of email clients. From the tests I've performed this seems to be the case, and [this article](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails) seems to confirm this.

Anyone have any input as to whether `<font>` tags are really necessary in HTML emails?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. They're unnecessary. Also, technically the `<font>` tag was deprecated starting with HTML 4, so you might as well remove it for that sake alone.

If you needed inline css styles on specific text, you would be better of using an inline-styled `<span>` tag than a `<font>` tag.

Campaign Monitor has a great and up-to-date resource on current [CSS support in emails](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: That's what I thought. These templates have pointless things like `<font face="Arial"><font color="#393"><font size="2">Some text</font></font></font>`. It's absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: @jwiscarson haha! I take over the task of using these templates to send weekly emails to over 100,000 customers on Monday (hold me)

Comment: As Syncro mentioned, the old FONT tag is needed to achieve some email styling, for example changing the color of an anchor is something that is hard in diferent email clients, this wont work fine in some clients: <a href="url-here"style="color:red">click here</a> but this will work in most all the cases: <a href="url-here"><font color="red">click here</font></a>.

Comment: Also <font face="arial">...</font> is an easy way to override the default font-family when coding for the stuborn Outlook.

Answer (score 73):

Sadly the accepted answer is not true, and even hideous things like @MrMisterMan's post are still *de rigeur*.

Deprecated as it may be, the font tag is *still* the only thing that works universally across pretty much all email clients, old and new. Bear in mind that email is not the web and it's still positively antediluvian. Some email services do unspeakable things; I've encountered one that blindly stripped all HTML tags (ignoring provided plain-text versions), converted linked images to attachments, resulting in an unreadable mess. Even contemplating having inline styles working in the face of such vandalism is truly wishful.

Want to know where the big hole is? Hotmail. hotmail, live.com and outlook.com strip or replace inline styles, yes, even in 2013. Blame Microsoft: hotmail, live, outlook.com and outlook have all got considerably worse in the last few years (e.g. floats were dropped from outlook.com 6 months ago; outlook dropped background images in 2007 and they've not been seen since).

Inline styles work in Gmail, but it strips anything outside the body tag. Some corporate mail filters (like BlackSpider/WebSense) do exactly the opposite, so if you want to be completely sure about your styling, you need to put a style tag in the head tag, another copy of it within the body (invalid, but it works), the same styles inline (look at the [premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca) project), and finally the same styling using font tags. Yes, it's insane, but no amount of wishing is going to make the problem go away. You can of course drop some of these, but by doing so you're implicitly accepting that it's not going to look the same in some places. You need to look at your audience - a new mobile music site can probably get away with it, but a corporate pension provider probably needs to be living in 2003 font-tag land.

Fortunately Apple Mail, iOS mail and iCloud all have vastly superior HTML handling (as that Campaign Monitor table shows, as does [the email standards project](http://www.email-standards.org/)). With the majority of mobile reading using some flavour of WebKit, rendering on mobile is generally much more consistent (and mostly better) than on desktops.

You could simply say that it's not worth the effort (what the accepted answer is effectively saying) - anyone using crappy mail readers clearly doesn't care that much what their email looks like, but that doesn't mean that your styling isn't going to break.

Comment: People with the crappy mail readers are probably used to seeing messed up html based emails anyways.

Comment: Apple and Gmail both add their own link highlighting that matches the OS rather than the email and require specific overrides to get rid of them.

Comment: "Deprecated as it may be, the font tag is still the only thing that works universally" - do you have any examples to back this up? All of the clients in your example handle <span> just as well as <font> as long as you use inline styles. The question isn't about using <style> blocks or <link> elements which I think is what your answer is referring to

Comment: When you have gmail stripping classes and IDs, hotmail removing style tags, link tags not working anywhere, and services like blackspider stripping style attributes, font tags are the only thing left standing. Generally I agree through - it's really not worth the effort - anyone using something that causes such vandalism clearly doesn't care what their messages look like, so you can't win, and there's not much point in trying too hard.

Comment: @Phil Outlook 2016 and Outlook.com, neither of which support most, if any, CSS attributes in the `style` attribute, and Outlook 2016 doesn't even properly support `<div>` elements, so if you're targetting anyone working at any company which uses Exchange then you're required to use tables and `<font>` tags. Guess who's currently fixing this exact problem at his desk job? >.<

Comment: @Benjamin I feel your pain but think you've misread the scope of this question. In the very old days we had to use something like `<font face="verdana" color="green">` whereas now (even in Outlook) we can at least use basic CSS, such as `<span style="font-family:verdana; color: green;">`

Comment: When you have services that strip inline styles (which still exist, mainly in the "enterprise" space), font tags are the only thing that remains working. It's true that many email clients *have* improved, just not by very much since this answer was written 5 years ago! Whether you need to scrape that hard at the bottom of the barrel depends on your audience.

Comment: @Phil Alas, wasn't working and we did indeed have to switch back to `<font>` tags. :<

Comment: @Synchro my policy was always that if a recipient uses a particularly niche client or spam filter which does something daft, then they're probably quite accustomed to everything being broken!

Comment: @Benjamin Nolan it would probably be useful for others who find this thread if you could be more specific about which client wasn't working and how. I'm yet to see an example more mainstream than 'blackspider'  mentioned above which strips inline style attributes

Comment: @Synchro: This answer is from a while back and It's now 2018... any chance that modernization has come to Hotmail, et. al. and we can now do something other than the `<FONT>` tag for styling?

Comment: Some clients have improved, Gmail in particular, but some have got worse, especially Outlook. Look at testing services like Email on acid and Litmus for detailed tests. You’re not out of the woods just yet!

Comment: @Ricketts all the more reason to give them an unbroken experience - it's an opportunity to get your head above the crowd.