# How can I change font in phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm planning to send an email with a font style of "century gothic" when received. I hope somebody can help me with my problem. 
I'm very thankful for your answers.

this is my code

```
$mail->Body = "

            <html>
                <head></head>
            <body>
                <b>Request ID:</b> $bodystring <br>
                <b>Type:</b> $bodystring1 <br>
                <b>Request:</b> $bodystring2 <br>
                <b>Status:</b> $bodystring3 <br>
                <b>Service:</b> $bodystring4 <br>
                <b>Request Date:</b> $bodystring5 <br>
                <b>Target Date:</b> $bodystring6 <br>
            </body>
";
```

Comment: html email is some what similar to HTML for a browser , you can add the css declaration to the head. not all email clients will support it, so in general i would keep it simple

Comment: like  <style>
.body
{
font-family:century gothic;
}
</style> ?

Comment: my answer is updated for you

Comment: Great! it works! Thank you very much for the answers. i just add style on head tag. :)) Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML email stylings is a minefield of issues, you basically need to revert back to HTML version 4.0 and style everything with inline `<font >` tags. You will also need to add font as a `<style> body{ }</style>` tag ***as well*** above the `<body>` tags of your email. There is a lot of reading material on the interet about this as it's a pain in the bum to make cross platform and cross system support. It still uses old tags and keeping as much styling inline as possible is the way. Do not bother calling outside style sheets they'll be dropped by the mailreader.

check SO for similar questions and for more exhaustive answers. Basically things get a lot easier if you don't want or don't need to support Micrsoft Live / Hotmail / Outlook email platform but even then it's still a faffy fiddle.

Please see this post by the guy who now looks after the PHPMailer project:
[Do we still need to use <font> tags in HTML emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012799/do-we-still-need-to-use-font-tags-in-html-emails/17292331#17292331)