# Font change and styling of HTML email body in MailKit

Tags: css, fonts, .net-core, mailkit

after allowing the access of less secure apps [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) I was able to send my self an email using gmail with inline styling.

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;   // for SmtpClient
using MimeKit;  // for MimeMessage, MailboxAddress and MailboxAddress

var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Hasan Yousef", "hasan@gmail.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Personal", "hasan@gmail.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Office", "hasan@offfice.com.sa"));
message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

string num = "13.5 million";

var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = @"
<div style='background-color:black;color:white;padding:20px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);'>
            <h1 style='text-align: center; font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;'>Welcome to Ben's Minecraft</h1>
            <img src='https://www.bk-international.com/mahout_cms/project/themes/default/images/de/logo.png' alt='HTML5' style='width:84px;height:47px'><br>
            <a href='https://www.bk-international.com/de_en/'>Bischof + Klein</a>
            <h2>London</h2>
            <p>London is the capital city of England. 
            It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over <span style='color:red'>
<i><b>" + num + 
@"</b></i></span>
inhabitants.</p>
            <p style='background-color:#ffc;color:black;'> Hope you liked the above</p>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>Description of A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>Description of B</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <ol>
                <li>London</li>
                <li>Paris</li>
                <li>Tokyo</li>
            </ol>
            <img src='https://www.bk-international.com/mahout_cms/project/themes/default/images/subhead.png' alt='HTML5' style='width:193px;height:9px'>
</div>         
            ";

message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

/*       message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = @"Hey Chandler,I just wanted to let you know that Monica and I were going to go play some paintball, you in?-- Joey"
        };
*/
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
      client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
      client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");  // due to enabling less secure apps access

      client.Authenticate("hasan@gmail.com", "myEmailPassward");
      client.Send(message);
      client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

My question is:
How can I change the font, I tried adding the head script below but it did not work.

```
<head>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

I noticed the font display in gmail is completely different than the font displayed in my outlook, so I need to unify the font to ensure everyone reads it the same way whatever email client he is using.

Comment: Did you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012799/do-we-still-need-to-use-font-tags-in-html-emails) topic ? it seems the same problem...

Have a look also at this site :https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for setting an acceptable font in all mail clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [E.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6089658/e-b) comment above, and refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012799/do-we-still-need-to-use-font-tags-in-html-emails) and [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and considering CSS in email is handled differently in different browsers and/or email clients, the most suitable option for me I found is using inline styling as per the below:

```
<div style='background-color:black;color:white;padding:20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica;color:#555555;font-size:12px;'>
```