# How can I resize an image to a percentage of itself with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to resize an image with a percentage of itself. For example, I just want to shrink the image by half by resizing it to 50%. But applying `width: 50%;` will resize the image to be 50% of the container element (the parent element which maybe the `<body>` for example).

Question is, can I resize the image with a percentage of itself without using JavaScript or server side? (I have no direct information of the image size)

I am pretty sure you cannot do this, but I just want to see whether there are intelligent CSS only solution. Thanks!

Comment: It will take up the percentage of the containing element if you would use `width: <number>%`. I don't think there is a way to do it!

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I have 2 methods for you.

### Method 1.

This method resize image only visual not it actual dimensions in DOM, and visual state after resize centered in middle of original size.

```css
img {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
```

***Browser support note:*** browsers statistics showed inline in `css`.

### Method 2.

```css
#wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#wrap img.fake {
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: auto;
}

#img_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#img_wrap img.normal {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img class="fake" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
  
  <div id="img_wrap">
    <img class="normal" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/cccccc" />
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note:*** `img.normal` and `img.fake` is the same image.
***Browser support note:*** This method will work in all browsers, because all browsers support `css` properties used in method.

#### The method works in this way:

1. `#wrap` and `#wrap img.fake` have flow
2. `#wrap` has `overflow: hidden` so that its dimensions are identical to inner image (`img.fake`)
3. `img.fake` is the only element inside `#wrap` without `absolute` positioning so that it doesn't break the second step
4. `#img_wrap` has `absolute` positioning inside `#wrap` and extends in size to the entire element (`#wrap`)
5. The result of the fourth step is that `#img_wrap` has the same dimensions as the image.
6. By setting `width: 50%` on `img.normal`, its size is `50%` of `#img_wrap`, and therefore `50%` of the original image size.

Comment: This doesn't resize the image to 50% of it's original size, it's now 50% of the parent of img_wrap..

Comment: See my updated answer for an attempt to solve the problem. What do you think?

Comment: I think it should be possible to use display:none instead of the visibility, like in my code. In your example, the space for the fake hidden image is still 'reserved' which screws up the flow if you would put content around it

Comment: it is impossible, because the main trick is in two nested and floated tags.

Comment: The `transform:scale()` solution has a big problem though. It doesn't interact well with the CSS box model. By which I mean that it doesn't interact with it *at all*, so you get layout which looks all wrong. See: http://jsfiddle.net/kahen/sGEkt/8/

Comment: i like the transform options, because i easily added animation to it (it's an image that gets bigger on hover)

Comment: how about refreshing the fiddles with fresh working images instead broken ones? that would be just awesome.

Comment: The problem is the container still takes the same amount of space.

Answer (score 63):

This has got to be one of the simplest solutions using the container element approach.

When using the container element approach, this question is a variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents). The trick is to let the container element shrinkwrap the child image, so it will have a size equal to that of the unsized image. Thus, when setting `width` property of the image as a percentage value, the image is scaled relative to its original scale.

Some of the other shrinkwrapping-enabling properties and property values are: `float: left/right`, `position: fixed` and `min/max-width`, as mentioned in the linked question. Each has its own side-effects, but `display: inline-block` would be a safer choice. Matt has mentioned `float: left/right` in his answer, but he wrongly attributed it to `overflow: hidden`.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"/>
    </span>
```

---

**Edit:** [As mentioned by trojan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20519964/3829636), you can also take advantage of the newly introduced [CSS3 intrinsic & extrinsic sizing module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/):

```css
figure {
  width: intrinsic;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
</figure>
```

However, [not all popular browser versions support it at the time of writing](http://caniuse.com/intrinsic-width).

Comment: @Anyone how to fix not collapsing span borders?  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqfY9/19/)

Comment: This was just what I needed... something quick and simple, thanks.  
I used it like this:

HTML:  
 `<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/>` 
CSS:  
`img { display: inline-block; width: 15%; }`

Comment: For future readers: the correct value to set on `figure` is `width: fit-content;` as of now. Browser support is also a lot better today.

Comment: you mean `max-content`?

Answer (score 17):

Scale the image:

```css
img {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
```

Answer (score 17):

This is a very old thread but I found it while searching for a simple solution to display retina (high res) screen capture on standard resolution display.

So there is an HTML only solution for modern browsers :

```
<img srcset="image.jpg 100w" sizes="50px" src="image.jpg"/>
```

This is telling the browser that the image is twice the dimension of it intended display size. The value are proportional and do not need to reflect the actual size of the image. One can use 2w 1px as well to achieve the same effect. The src attribute is only used by legacy browsers.

The nice effect of it is that it display the same size on retina or standard display, shrinking on the latter.

Answer (score 16):

Another solution is to use:

```
<img srcset="example.png 2x">
```

It won't validate because the `src` attribute is required, but it works (except on any version of IE because `srcset` is not supported).

Comment: I am conflicted between this which doesn't validate and @Max_B which validates but uses a slight hack. Hey ho!

Comment: Actually @ChrisPink, since posting this answer I realized that you can just add the same image as the `src` which will validate. The image will always be sized properly in browsers that support `srcset` (all modern browsers).

Answer (score 3):

This actually is possible, and I discovered how quite by accident while designing my first large-scale responsive design site.

The overflow:hidden gives the wrapper height and width, despite the floating contents, without using the clearfix hack. You can then position your content using margins. You can even make the wrapper div an inline-block.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  float: left; /* Note: 'float:right' would work too */
}

.box>img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function shrinkImage(idOrClass, className, percentShrinkage){
'use strict';
    $(idOrClass+className).each(function(){
        var shrunkenWidth=this.naturalWidth;
        var shrunkenHeight=this.naturalHeight;
        $(this).height(shrunkenWidth*percentShrinkage);
        $(this).height(shrunkenHeight*percentShrinkage);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    'use strict';
     shrinkImage(".","anyClass",.5);  //CHANGE THE VALUES HERE ONLY. 
});
```

This solution uses js and jquery and resizes based only on the image properties and not on the parent. It can resize a single image or a group based using class and id parameters.

for more, go here: https://gist.github.com/jennyvallon/eca68dc78c3f257c5df5

Answer (score -2):

I think you are right, it's just not possible with pure CSS as far as I know (not cross-browser I mean).

Ok I didn't like my answer very much so I puzzled a little. I might have found an interesting idea which could help out.. maybe it IS possible after all (although not the prettiest thing ever):

Tested and working in Chrome, FF and IE 8&9. It doesn't work in IE7.

```css
#img_wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#rescaled_img_wrap {
  width: 50%;
}

#original_img {
  display: none;
}

#rescaled_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_wrap">
  <img id="original_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
  <div id="rescaled_img_wrap">
    <img id="rescaled_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/dddddd" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your example resize image not proportionally

Comment: Your method makes it possible to decrease image through window resizing

Comment: it is because you are using `inline-block`, that's why width `#img_wrap` depends not only inner html width, but also on context-container width.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that display:none image does nothing and can be removed. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -3):

This is a not-hard approach:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}

img,
div {
  width: ##%;
  height: ##%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
</div>
```

Comment: This makes it a % of its container, not of the size of itself.

Answer (score -3):

Although it does not answer the question directly, one way to scale images is relative to the size (especially width) of the **viewport**, which is mostly the use case for responsive design. No wrapper elements needed.

```css
img {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" />
```