# Css how to set img sizes non relative of the parent

Tags: html, css

```
@media screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
  img {

    max-width: 50% !important;
  }
}
```

I'am trying to make the images lower sizes, but different images are acting different, some of them are getting bigger instead of getting the 50% lower they are, some are getting lower is it should, how can I force the images to resize 50% of itself, not of the parent

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself

Answer (score 0):

Percentages represent the size of the window, and then each element will be relative to its parent,

```
<body>
  <div>
     <img />
  </div>
</body>
```

If we ask the div to be 50% it will be 50% of the size of the window, then if we ask the image to be 40% it will be 40% the size of the parent div, so 40% of 50%. **It has nothing to do with the original size of the image.**

Instead get the original size of the image and assign the value, if the image is 500px then say `width:250px;`

Or use JS or Jquery:

```
$('img').width($('img').width()/2);
```