# How to rescale image relative to its own size in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

How to re-scale image relative to its own size in HTML and CSS?

I want an image to be scale up to `170%` of its own size, or scale it down to `50%` of its own size rather than the size if it's parent element.

I've tried this:

```
<div><img src="0001.svg" height="50%"></div>
```

it re-scales relative to its parent element's height.

Comment: Just set its height or width to the percentage you want. Post the code you are using so we can help you.

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<script>
function Start() {
OPIC = document.getElementById('PIC')
var x=OPIC.width, y=x=OPIC.height, pct=.7 // = 70%
OPIC.height=pct*y; OPIC.width=pct*x;
}
</script>
<body onload="Start()">
<img id='PIC' src=...>
```

However with IE and Edge I seem to be losing the picture

Comment: I forgot `</script>

Answer (score -3):

Specify some width for parent div.Then give either width or height for the image  to maintain aspect ratio of the image.

Here is the **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/DG2KP/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="image_resize">
        <img src="http://www.sxc.hu/img/certified_images/crt_melaniemar.jpg" />
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .image_resize {
        width:260px;
    }
    .image_resize img {
        width:60%;
    }
```