# Making Retina bullet points with images

Tags: html, css, retina

I currently have a customer image that I am using in stead of bullet points. I have that set up with the following CSS and it works fine:

```
ul.benefits {
    list-style-image: url('/images/bullet-point-circle.png');
}
```

The trouble is that the image that I am using is purposely double the size that it needs to be so that it can be Retina quality... But I cannot seem to find a way to specify the height of the image being used as the bullet points... Is there any other way to get the image to show as Retina (the 2x version scaled down to 12 by 12 as opposed to the actual size of 24 x 24)?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself.

Comment: i don't think that is possible... one of the ways you can achieve that is by using the image as background of li and then setting the padding/margin etc.

Comment: @JX16 I suppose. I could just set a height though. The problem isn't how to resize it, but how to resize it while using it as a bullet point...

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like this to achieve the same effect:

(remove the bullet points and set a `background` to your `li` and then make some adjustments)

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
}

ul li{
 background:url('http://bowlingballexchange.com/applied/misc/facebook24by24.gif') no-repeat left;
    background-size:12px 12px;
}


ul li span{
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

html:

```
<ul>

<li><span>list 1</span></li>

<li><span>list 2</span></li>

<li><span>list 3</span></li>

<li><span>list 4</span></li>

<ul>
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/o17sfjto/

if you want this to work with multi-line text... you can use a different workaround, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SGz75/4/

```
<ul class="test">
<li><div class="bullet"></div><div class="one">Text Text Text</div></li>
<li><div class="bullet"></div><div class="one">Long Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div></li>
<li><div class="bullet"></div><div class="one">Text Text Text</div></li>
```

css:

```
.test {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

li > div{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    //background:red;
    width:5%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.one{
    width:95%;
}

.bullet{
height:20px;
width:20px;  background:url('http://bowlingballexchange.com/applied/misc/facebook24by24.gif') no-repeat left;
    background-size:12px 12px;
}
```

Comment: This is very close, but they are misaligned vertically... I want the bullet point to line up with the first line of a particular list item, not the center of it...

Comment: Try extending on of the list items in the JsFiddle so that it breaks onto a second line, and you will see what I mean...

Comment: Thank you! Very cool. (If not a little tedious for something that I would have thought was simple :))