# Zoom on an image inside an iframe not working on IE and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an image where the zoom works on all the browsers, but when i open it inside an `iframe`, the zoom stops working in IE and Google Chrome, but works fine in Firefox.

How do I fix this issue?

The link to the image - found it on the internet.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://www.dobble.net.au/help/template.jpg" style="align:left;vertical-align:top;border-width:0px;" name="AisIFrame"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qL75khzg/

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself

Comment: I don't see any type of *zoom* action being applied to an image in this demo. What exactly do you mean by "zoom"? Also, which version(s) of Internet Explorer are you testing?

Comment: if you open this [link](http://www.dobble.net.au/help/template.jpg) the image you can zoom on it in all browser. but if you open it in an iframe the zoom work only in Firefox, in Chrome and all IE versions dont work. the zoom css is in Firefox ImageDocument */

media not print {
  .overflowing {
    cursor: zoom-out;
  }

  .shrinkToFit {
    cursor: zoom-in;
  }
}
@JonathanSampson

Comment: @leb: the image link you provided returns to me a DNS error, please check

Answer (score 0):

Even Opera Browser is affected of the same issue. It is an issue that affects IE and Chromium derived browser (and perhaps not only). Chrome and Opera are both derived from Chromium browser project. After testing the issue on IE, FF, Op, Ch, Firefox is the only one that behaves right.
I've sent to respective developers (but MS) a bug notice with the issue more times in the past, but as far as I can see the issue is still there unfortunately.

Anyway to try to solve the problem insert into the iframe another html/css page instead loading the image directly into the iframe and load the image into the html page within the html tag "img". Than style that tag with the css style sheet as you wish giving the img the size you need. Also, depending on what you need, you may evaluate to wrap the img tag into a styled div to contain img size. If properly done de css part, the img will match in size to the container div scaling proportionally, without shrinking/deforming.

Done that let's try now the implementation of the zoom function.
Well for this it is needed a javascript event attached to the element that you want to zoom (the div for ex.). The event would be "onclick" (or "click" if you want to use addEventListener js method. Also you can zoom even without any js using ":over" css pseudoclass (in the example is used once to compare the different behavior).

The following example will explicate how the whole trick works:

```js
function zoom(el)
{
  var checksize = el.style.width == "100%";
  if (checksize)
      {
        el.style.width = "";
        el.style.height = "";
      }
      else
      {
        el.style.width = "100%";
        el.style.height = "100%";
      }
}
```

```css
.h
{
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.v
{
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

img
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.v:hover
{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="v" onclick="zoom(this)">
  <img src='http://download.4-designer.com/files/20150801/It-is-said-that-there-is-no-second-wave-of-copyright-free-image-collection-54650.jpg'/> 
</div>

<div class="h" onclick="zoom(this)">
  <img src='http://download.4-designer.com/files/20150801/It-is-said-that-there-is-no-second-wave-of-copyright-free-image-collection-54650.jpg'/> 
</div>
```

Also remember that the iframe is not the only html tag that allows you to show an external content (the image in this case). In fact you can use the 'img' tag itself, the 'embed' tag, the 'object' tag and even the 'div' tag or other tags that accept the background to be styled with an image. In this last case you can show an image into it by setting its 'background-image' css style property to the image you want to show into it.