# flex display ignores scale transform of content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transforms

I use a container with `display: flex` and scaling to the width of the website. The content of the container are several links inside div-elements with a `transform:scale(1.5,1)` for aesthetical reasons. However the flexbox seems to ignore the scaling of the CSS transform and when they get to big they just overlap and also won't wrap around lines (even with set `flex-wrap: wrap`). Example:

```css
#flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-content {
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scale(1.5, 1);
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 98px;
  width: 98px;
  /* 98px since the border gets added around resulting in 100px */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox-container">
  <div class="inner-content"></div>
  <div class="inner-content"></div>
  <div class="inner-content"></div>
  <div class="inner-content"></div>
</div>
```

Does someone maybe know a trick how to get the flexbox calculate with the transformed sizes?

Comment: Transform does not affect the position of other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by adopting an answer in [CSS image resize percentage of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself).

I use a hidden version of the text with scaled up font size (this requires that you know the current font size and multiply it by your transform scale) for the size of the flex element. The actual tranformed element gets `position:absolute` and positioned at `left:0`. This is the result:

```css
#flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-content {
  position: relative;

  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner-content .fake {
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 1.67rem;
  height: 1.5ex;
}

.inner-content .span_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scale(1.67, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox-container">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <span class="fake">
      Lorem
    </span>
    <div class="span_wrap">
      Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-content">
    <span class="fake">
      ipsum
    </span>
    <div class="span_wrap">
      ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-content">
    <span class="fake">
      dolor
    </span>
    <div class="span_wrap">
      dolor
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-content">
    <span class="fake">
      sit
    </span>
    <div class="span_wrap">
      sit
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-content">
    <span class="fake">
      amet
    </span>
    <div class="span_wrap">
      amet
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flex-grow` instead of `transform:scale1.5,1)`.

Here a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/0e1qajvb/1/)

Comment: That does not solve the problem. I actually want `transform:scale(1.5,1)` because there is text inside the grey boxes which should get stretched out. Also my flex container has a set width and items should wrap on multiple lines if the space is not sufficient. What I would need is maybe an element which has 150% of the width of the element I use transform on.

Comment: @RenéMartin, I updated the fiddle with some text. `flex-grow` is definitly the way to go if you want tot use flex, if you haven't ready read this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) take a look.

Comment: I still need the transform because my text must be stretched for typographical reasons. This is what the final should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/0e1qajvb/3/ (I hard coded the width properties of the inner span-elements which should equal to 150% of the actual calculated with based on its content)