# CSS : How to resize an image based on its own size, not on its container

Tags: html, css, image

I followed this problem : [CSS image resize percentage of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself)

But in my case, nothing works.

I have 4 images I would like to fit inside a container.  I've tried putting them in another div container and then adjusting their width in %, but it keeps adjusting to the width of the parent.

the solution I have is to keep playing with the width % of the img to get what I want. And I made them as flex items.

Is there a way to adjust the size of the images based on their own size?

What I want is, if I enter `img { width : 50%;}` I want it to be 50% if the image. Not the container. I've tried this way in my code, but not successful.

I can Imagine that having a fixed width container would make it work, but how about this `width : max-container or fit-content`?Doesn't seem to make what I thought.

```css
.terms-of-service h2 {
  text-align: left;
}

.terms-of-service p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.small-logos {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.small-logos img {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="terms-of-service col-content">
  <h2>Terms of Service</h2>
  <p>This site uses cookies. By continuing to use this site you are agreeing to our use of cookies. Please refer to <a href="#">Google's Privacy Terms</a> and <a href="#">Terms of Service</a> to see how cookies are used.</p>
  <div class="small-logos"><img src="https://www.sabico.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/slocaliza2.jpg" alt="BBB"><img src="https://www.sabico.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/slocaliza2.jpg" alt="25y"><img src="https://www.sabico.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/slocaliza2.jpg" alt="green"><img src="https://www.sabico.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/slocaliza2.jpg"
      alt="Env"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself?noredirect=1&lq=1) has some interesting ideas. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Haha, that's the one I am referring to...

Comment: ooooh this is an interesting problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried grid? Within a grid, setting a percentage width of an item will make it a percentage of the allocated width the grid has given that item.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); // 4 equal grid items

  .image {
    width: 100%; // image will 25% of container
  }

  .halfWidthImage {
    width: 50%; // image will be 12.5% of container. half the width of it's allocated grid space
  }
}
```

It's not exactly what you want but I believe it's the closest you'll get with pure CSS

Comment: Note i've used SCSS-style nesting. obviously make it flat if you are using plain CSS

Comment: I have not yet used grids... I can try! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: No worries. let me know how it goes!

Comment: In the event my images are not the same size? Would grid still work?

Comment: yes. just a slightly different configuration. remove the line `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)` which defines a specific amount of columns in a row.
Instead use `grid-auto-flow: column` which does what it says on the tin.

Comment: to be honest, i'm relatively new to Grid too and the solution in the answer might work for you. give it a go

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is `.terms-of-service` to be resizable and the 4 image resize with it. You want images to stay in proportion while resizing. But changing width stretches them.
If that is the case, then you can try `object-fit: contain;` property. Or set aspect ratio of each image using `aspect-ratio: 250/100;` property to keep them in proper shape.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .terms-of-service h2 {
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .terms-of-service p {
      margin: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .small-logos {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .small-logos img {
      width: 10%;
      object-fit: contain;
       /*aspect-ratio: 2/1;*/
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="terms-of-service col-content">
    <h2>Terms of Service</h2>
    <p>This site uses cookies. By continuing to use this site you are agreeing to our use of cookies. Please refer to <a href="#">Google's Privacy Terms</a> and
      <a href="#">Terms of Service</a> to see how cookies are used.</p>
    <div class="small-logos"><img src="https://www.sabico.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/SABICO-group.png" alt="BBB" /><img src="https://www.sabico.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/rsc.jpg" alt="25y" /><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/24/WWF_logo.svg/188px-WWF_logo.svg.png"
        alt="green" /><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Bass_logo.svg/255px-Bass_logo.svg.png" alt="Env" /></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Go in full page mode and resize browser window.

---

But if you are looking for adjusting dimensions based on image's actual size then here is what specification says:

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is outside the scope of CSS; they're external objects whose representation is independent of the CSS formatting model.
>
> Put in simpler terms, they're elements whose contents are not affected by the current document's styles. The position of the replaced element can be affected using CSS, but not the contents of the replaced element itself. Some replaced elements, such as  elements, may have stylesheets of their own, but they don't inherit the styles of the parent document.
>
> The only other impact CSS can have on a replaced element is that there are properties which support controlling the positioning of the element's content within its box.

> Typical replaced elements are:
>
> - `<iframe>`
> - `<video>`
> - `<embed>`
> - `<img>`

This makes sense, because if you change dimensions of your 'Terms of Service` box then you'll have to actually go and edit all 4 images in photo editing software to change their dimensions to keep them consistent with the theme.

For more information refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element