# How to resize image via CSS as a percentage of itself in a container that is just big enough?

Tags: html, css, image

How can I resize two images via a percentage of themselves (their native size) and have those images appear horizontally adjacent without space between them?

The trouble I am having is the containing divs appear to be sized according to the contained images original dimensions, not the resized dimensions. Setting `display:inline-block;` does prevent them from wrapping, but only if the width of the view is wide enough to accommodate the *original* image sizes. It does not reduce the size of the div. I feel like I am overlooking something obvious, but am too close to see it.

This code is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026615/9300908) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397049/css-image-resize-percentage-of-itself). I tried it with figure elements instead of divs per the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026615/9300908) and with many variations with no luck.

Some of the other answers I was not able to use because my solution constrained to an antiquated wiki html editor that filters out attributes and tags it does not like on save (e.g. `srcset`).

```css
.img-box {
  width: fit-content;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-box img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I mean a portion of their native size. I have a group of screen captures of various sizes. I am rendering thumbnails of them embedded on a wiki. Being shrunk by different amounts looks funny when two images are showing parts of a screen capture, and the apparent size of similar visual elements are different. I realize I could make my own thumbnails and simply use them instead.

Imagine a wiki page is documenting the release notes of a new version of software and the images are screen caps of the new features. You would want objects in the thumbnails to have the same apparent size.

Comment: Note the problem I'm having in the code snippet is that divs are not reducing to the size of the rendered thumbnails. The images themselves are reducing correctly.

Comment: Also, the question referenced in the comment is the same one I referenced in my question. I am attempting to follow some of the solutions in the answers to it.