# Stretch parent to child with float:left

Tags: css, css-float

I use overflow:hidden; but it is not stretch...=(

This is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9NNYN/

Comment: Your jsfiddle shows the parent `div` stretched all the way across the screen in FF. You need to describe your problem better...

Comment: Giving them a percentage width helps, however you will never be able to get it exact with a border and/or 6 elements; 100 doesn't divide by 6 with no remainder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [`overflow:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow) does what you think it does. :) If you want to make the parent width equal to the child width, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents).