# Div width doesn't increase with it's content

Tags: css, html, width

In my application I have tags that can be from 5 to 15 characters. By that reason the tags width differ, but the surrounding divs increases with the parents width, not the content.

What should I put in the CSS to make the divs width adapt to the width of it's content?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<div class="tag">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="content">Test album</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="album">X</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.tag {
    background: red;
}
```

**Test case**: http://jsfiddle.net/T4XJ3/1/

Comment: Make sure the div doesn't get given a width from another rule applied to it non-directly. Also make sure  it's parents are also not given an explicit width. A tool like Chrome's inspector or Firebug is indispensable here.

Comment: A [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/) would make your question easier to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make CSS Div Width Equal To Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<div>` element has `display:block`, so it will always take the full width of their container.

You can make them "flexible" by using `display: inline-block` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T4XJ3/5/)).

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Was going to suggest float, but... :) +'d

Answer (score 2):

inline-block to the rescue!

```
div.tag {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

From the w3c spec:

> This value causes an element to generate an inline-level
>   block container.  The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a
>   block box, and the element  itself is formatted as an atomic
>   inline-level box.

In simpler terms this means that outside of your div it acts like a span would (sizes to fit contents, flows inline in content, etc.), and inside of your div it acts like a div normally would (for positioning, sizing, padding, etc.).