# How to maintain flexiblity of images in a given width

Tags: javascript

How can we maintain flexibility of images in a given width,
Example:I have a div width of 500px right now i have placed 4 images in that in future i will add 4 more images to same div the images should flexibly fit in that width

Comment: Are they meant to on the same horizontal line?

Comment: No, In a given width and height is should fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the div width to width:auto; dont restrict it to 500px!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this question [make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents) which could help you in the right direction.