# child with min-width grows to size of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` that I want to center (margin auto) and grow as content fills it, so I'm using min-width and min-height to accomplish this, but what's happening is the child `<div>` is taking on the parent's(`<body>`) width instead.

How can I prevent this from happening?

example: http://jsfiddle.net/kRF5d/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make CSS Div Width Equal To Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents)

Comment: yeah, from that post it looks like i'll need to do it via js

Answer (score 1):

Since `div` is a block-level element, it's going to fill the entire width of the parent unless a proper `width` is set. I recommend applying `display: inline-block;` to the child `div`.

Comment: This is nice, but then it becomes hard to center the `div`. `left: 50%; margin-left: -25px;` works, but then when it gets bigger, it wont really be centered. Anyway... just sharing my thoughts.

Comment: I tried doing this on his fiddle (inline-block) and wasn't able to center it, BTW. My first thought as well.

Comment: Apply `text-align: center` to the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Just change position to absolute from relative.

```
#top {
    min-width:10%;
    min-height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: yeah, that works, but then when it changes sizes, it doesn't push the rest of the page content down, and its difficult to center it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your #top div to be %100 width then give it a width.

http://jsfiddle.net/kRF5d/3/

Comment: if i do that then how will it grow when new elements are added to it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is because min-width sets the *minimum* width, it doesn't limit the maximum width. So because divs display as block-level elements, it automatically grows to the same width as the parent element.

So while I don't know specifically what you're trying to accomplish with this, that's the reason it's not working as expected.

Comment: I want for it to grow as new elements are added to it or when current elements change size

Comment: Yes, I understand that. This is the reason yours isn't working. The other solutions posted will help you expand it properly (span with block-inline), but won't get you to centering it. That's the part I'm stuck on as well.

Comment: I'm creating a lightbox were each image will be of a different size so I'm trying to keep it centered when it's width changes. i guess the only solution would be js?

Comment: No. If it's simply images, then just center the div, make it however wide the widest image will be or larger, and apply text-align:center to it. Images which are placed inside will center (they may need to be inside a paragraph tag.