# CSS: Max-Width won't shrink?

Tags: css, text, size, width, shrink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make CSS Div Width Equal To Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents)

I am trying to make a chat like application but now I ran acros a little bug of some sort.

I have a div with a max-width set to 350px. But when I put the following text in it:

dddddddddddd ddddddddddd dddddddddd dddddddddd

It will add new lines at every space but the width of the div will stay at 100px. I made a little example in jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5t2hm/12/

As you can see the width of the yellow box is 100px while I want it to shrink to the width of the text. I also tried to fix it with using a  element but the yellow box remains the same.

Bascily I want it to look like the third box while retaining the max-width part.

Does someone got any idea how the yellow box will shrink to the width of the text?

Comment: But in fiddle have width is 100px!. you change 100px to 350px.

Comment: true. I made the example a little smaller but the problem still remains. I also tried the other page as mentioned by Álvaro G. Vicario. But I am still having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this [**fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/5t2hm/14/) or [**fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/5t2hm/15/).

Instead of using one `div` use two `div`'s (or)
one `div` and one `span`. I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use para

```
<p></P>
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t2hm/11/)

Comment: Not exactly where I was looking for. Basicly I want it to look like the third box in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5t2hm/12/

But the third box doesn´t have a max-width set but that is needed for the project.

Comment: yeah i am ready to help you. But i did not understood. Can you please insert image here..

Comment: I am sorry. I rechecked your answer and indeed the behavior of the div will change if I add the <p> tags. However this is not possible because its supposed to render human input and then I need to check for a way that it will add <p> tags when a certain sentance is too long. However with the tags it rendered correctly! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The default width of a DIV is 100%, so max-width is just capping that in your fiddle - it won't consider the width of the content.

To shrink your DIV to its content you'd need `display: inline-block;` or `float:left; width:auto;`.

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/