# display: inline-block does not make width as small as possible with wrapped contents

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that has `inline-block` and a `max-width` set on it, as well as some text content that may wrap inside. My problem is that the `div` always takes the maximum width possible, **but only if the text wraps**. I wish to make the `div` take the smallest width possible, in response to text wrapping.

```css
div {
 
  max-width: 120px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;

  border: 1px solid black;    
  padding: 0.2rem;
  
}
```

```html
<div>Reallylongword test</div>
```

**Actual Result**:
[image: Actual Result]

**Desired Result**:
[image: Desired Result]

---

This does not work with restricting the `width` with a parent, either.

I have searched around, and my code is using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents). I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12673003/2486953) ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t2hm/31/)), but it just doesn't work.
I am of aware using `word-break: break-all`, but that is just really ugly.

Thank you.

---

**Update**

I am trying to make a navbar. It is currently using flexbox, not `display: inline-block`. I just (or at least I thought I did) isolated the problem to single nav element. Apparantly, not all the answers seemed to match my original navbar problem. I'm sorry. I will preserve the original post if I don't get an answer to my actual problem.

Comment: The width is being assigned as `max-width`.  Pretty neat as I agree, logically `max-width` should be ONLY the maximum width leaving the minimum to `auto` + `padding`.  My suggestion is to max the `max-width` smaller.  Neat little glitch tho  :)

Comment: You can't do this (without JS)

Comment: possible duplicate: [Make container shrink-to-fit child elements as they wrap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/3597276)

Answer (score 9):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451074/1869660) in one of your linked questions: `display: table-caption` instead of `inline-block` does what you want.

```css
div {
  max-width: 120px;
  width: auto;
  display: table-caption;

  border: 1px solid black;    
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div>Reallylongword test</div>
```

Comment: Although this does work given my expressed problem. It is my fault that I did not explain what situation I was using it for: a navbar. My current navbar uses flexbox. This solution does not work with flexbox or floats.

Comment: With flexbox, you often need to put each item in a wrapper div. It's hard to give any advice without knowing your exact markup, but here is an example where the two first items (with wrappers) look like expected: https://jsfiddle.net/ukcguxg9/

Comment: I also discovered that your solution is not responsive to either `max-width` or the length of the words inside. It just breaks it no matter what, equivalent to a `<br>`. I've modified my question to make it clear that I want it to be responsive.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the span tag. It's an inline element and inline elements are only as wide as what's inside it. Once you've used span you can change display: inline-block to just display: inline;

I hope this helps

```css
div {
 
  max-width: 120px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline;

  border: 1px solid black;    
  padding: 0.2rem;
  
}
```

```html
<div><span>Reallylongword test</span></div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the text completely ignores its boundaries and doesn't wrap. If I set a max-width to the container, the container doesn't resize to the smallest possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply how browsers size an element when text wraps. The same thing happens with table cells. If you are using very specific, static content you could put a hard break `<br/>` where you want the text to wrap. This solves the issue but leaves your content very inflexible. However considering you are being very specific in your container size this might work for you.

Would it be possible to see your content and the design you are trying to achieve? It would help with offering solutions.

Comment: I have a flex box navbar, with only a parent and children elements. When I resize the window, some nav items' text wrap, thus my problem. 

On another note, `<br/>`s *might* work along with media queries or JS.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Fabian's answer above, this is a consequence of how browsers resize elements to handle word wrap. For this reason, I don't believe a pure CSS solution is possible. However, you can dynamically determine the width and force the `<div>` to that width:

```
var textWidth = $("div").textWidth();
$("div").width(textWidth);
```

The function I am using to caluclate `textWidth` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width).

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
  var html_org = $(this).html();
  var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
  $(this).html(html_calc);
  var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
  $(this).html(html_org);
  return width;
};
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13zx9grq/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score -1):

Can you adjust your `max-width` value like below?

```css
div {
 
  max-width: 110px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;

  border: 1px solid black;    
  padding: 0.2rem;
  
  
}
```

```html
<div>Reallylongword test</div>
```