# Span will take the max-width size in case the content breaks on multiple rows

Tags: html, css

Let's assume we have a `<span>` element with the following css:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

In case our text is short and it fits in only one row, the width of the span will have exactly the width of the content. Otherwise, if the text is larger and it needs to break on multiple lines, the width of the span will be exactly the max-width (250px) and not the width of the content.

I would like my `span` to always have the width of the content itself. Is this possible somehow?

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<span style="background-color: green">Lorem ipsum</span>
<br>
<br>
<span  style="background-color: red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
```

Comment: This happens because on the first line, the text `consectetur` tries to fill up the whole first line. When it's not able to, it goes to the line below leaving the whole width used on the first line. There's no going around this. If you tell us *why* you need to do this we might give you alternatives.

Comment: Oh, and your question was asked before here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389292/display-inline-block-does-not-make-width-as-small-as-possible-with-wrapped-cont

Answer (score -1):

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 250px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<span style="background-color: green">Lorem ipsum</span>
<br>
<br>
<span  style="background-color: red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
```

Comment: This is still not the result the OP asked for.... And if it is, then it's a duplicate i.e the question I linked in the comments.

Comment: There would be a problem with the word-breaking (for the word "consectetur", the first part, consectet" is on the first line and the second part, "ur" is on the second line)

Comment: @AndreiRosu yep that's what `word-break: break-all` does, take a look at the question and answer I linked under the post.