# How do I prevent multiline text from filling the entire width of the parent element

Tags: css, text, multiline

Suppose I have a container element that has a set width. I have a content element with a display inline-block that can contain some text. This text could be so big that it has to be filled over several lines. The problem with this is that default behaviour for multiline text is that it grows the element to the complete width of the parent element.

Imagine the following example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Firstreallongword11 Secondalsolongword22 Thirdwordthatisconsiderablylonger
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 260px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

Because these are long words, they will be positioned over multiple lines. What I would expect for the `.content` element, is that it would grow to the maximum width of the largest word on one single row.
But as you can see, because it consists of multiple lines, the element grows to the max width of `.container` .

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a67pLmyf/)**

What I want to achieve is, `.content` gaining the width of the largest item on a single row, as it would with one single lin:

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/he8d9xtf/)**

Is there any way to achieve this with pure css/html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display: inline-block does not make width as small as possible with wrapped contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389292/display-inline-block-does-not-make-width-as-small-as-possible-with-wrapped-cont)

Comment: The `display: table-caption` method mentioned in the linked duplicate should be able to achieve this. https://jsfiddle.net/9axvh6ey/

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: No, you can't do that with pure CSS.

But here is a solution anyway, which is a bit of a hack: It uses `display: table-cell;` for the `.content` element, and a rather small `width` value (which will adjust to the actual value of the longest word and acts like a `min-width` setting in this case):

```css
.container {
  width: 260px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}
.content {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Firstreallongword11 Secondalsolongword22 Thirdwordthatisconsiderablylonger
  </div>
</div>
```