center div with text doesn't work when viewport gets narrow
I have a div (.quote) in which another div (.centered) should be centered inside the viewport (here simulated with anohter div). The text inside .centered should be left-aligned. The text has some predefined linebreaks, but should break on other words as well if necessary.


.viewport {
  width: 440px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.quote {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .txt {
    font-size: 64px;
  }
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="quote">
    <div class="centered">      
      <span class="txt">This is a long text, with a<br>predefined linebreak</span>
      <br>
      <span class="author">It's me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>



This works fine as long as the viewport is wide enough (delete width in class viewport):

But as soon as it gets narrow, the div.centered isn't centered anymore (set viewport.width to 440px):

As you can see, the text is now suddenly left aligned, leaving a space on the right side.
What might be the problem and how can I get rid of it?
Edit: This is what I expected:


It's still "centered", it's just taking up the entire width of the element.  In your browser's debugging tools, incrementally increase/decrease that same width value and observe the container growing/shrinking.  For the text container, the width is defined by its widest content.  Which is the first line of text before the line break.  And that text is always left-aligned here, at any viewport width.  My point is, it's not really clear to me what behavior you're expecting otherwise.

Thanks for your reply. I added a faked image what I expected: The div.centered should only be as wide as the text reaches (and not get the same size as the container).

Basically the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/41389292/1427878

@Werner: By what rules are you looking to implement that result?  Should the text container have a maximum width?  Should the parent container have a padding?  Should the flex box have three elements instead of one, and the outer two elements have a minimum width?  Something else?

Thanks for your replies. The text should be as wide as possible inside the viewport having as few as possible linebreaks (except the ones that are predefined).
