# CSS - parent div is not expanding to width/height of child

Tags: css, html

I am looking to overlay a caption on to an image. I have managed to do this, but the image is expanding out of the parent `div`.

I have the containing `div` set to `inline-block`, as I want it to 'auto size', not take up `width: 100%`. If you look at the current output, you'll see the image could be within the black bordered box.

It only needs to work in Chrome, if you encounter cross-browser issues.

Thanks in advance!

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AaXTm/)**

---

***CSS:***

```css
#body_content {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    display: inline-block;    
    padding: 5px;
}
#body_header {
    border: solid 1px red;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#body_image {
    position: absolute;
}
#body_image_caption {
    color: white;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#body_image_container {
    background: white;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#body_image_overlay {
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;    
}​
```

***HTML:***

```
<div id="body_content">
   <div id="body_header">
      Heading
   </div>
   <div id="body_image_container">
      <div id="body_image">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/s6G8n.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
          <div id="body_image_overlay">
             <div id="body_image_caption">
                Some Text
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should assign `inline-block` to the `body-image`, otherwise the browser gets confused which width to use. Can't check now.

Comment: there are many reasons why this might happen, to see a few, try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `#body_image` element is escaping from the `#body_image_container` because its `position` is set to `absolute`.  Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document's flow, causing parent elements to collapse as though the child element wasn't there.  If you change it to `relative`, then it becomes contained within the black box:

```css
#body_image{
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AaXTm/2/

Answer (score 8):

Try this css in parent div.

```
Overflow:auto
```

Comment: Worked well for me, but should be `overflow: auto;` (lowercase).
Edit: `display: inline-block;` from comments above was better, avoiding unnecessary scrollbars.

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle. You need to set the position of the child element of the image to be absolute and the parent element to be relative. Change the width of the caption accordingly.

```css
child-element {
    position:absolute;
}

parent-element {
    position:relative
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AaXTm/4/