# Cant center form?

Tags: html, css

So `#container` is already centered, but I can't seem to get the `<form>` centered. I want to have everything inside the form horizontally centered and for some reason it's not working. I've tried every trick that I know.

```
<!-- Container Start -->
<div id="container">
  <h1 class="signup-header-text">SIGN UP</h1>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <form class="signup-form" action="#" method="post">
    <div id="first_step">
      <div class="form">
        <label for="gender">You are:</label>
        <br />
        <select id="gender" name="gender" size="2">
          <option value="1">Male</option>
          <option value="2">Female</option>
        </select>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="" />
    </div>
  </form>
<div id="progress_bar">
       <div id="progress"></div>
       <div id="progress_text">0% Complete</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Container End -->
```

My CSS

```
#container {
    height: 410px;
    min-height: 410px;
    min-width: 756px;
    width: 756px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -205px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -378px; /* Half the width */
    background: #e9e5e5;
    border: solid #dcdcdc 2px;
    outline: solid #c4c4c4 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added text-align: center;

```
#container {
height: 410px;
min-height: 410px;
min-width: 756px;
width: 756px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -205px; /* Half the height */
margin-left: -378px; /* Half the width */
background: #e9e5e5;
border: solid #dcdcdc 2px;
outline: solid #c4c4c4 1px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
text-align: center;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjL7t/

Answer (score 1):

Simply center your text.

```
#container {
    height: 410px;
    min-height: 410px;
    min-width: 756px;
    width: 756px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    **text-align:center;**
    margin-top: -205px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -378px; /* Half the width */
    background: #e9e5e5;
    border: solid #dcdcdc 2px;
    outline: solid #c4c4c4 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.signup-form {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It works with <center></center> tags why did they have to get eliminated :/

Comment: try adding display:block; also define a width.

Answer (score 0):

Find the element you want to center, set a width, and set `margin: 0 auto` on it.

```
.signup-form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EXLSJ/

If you don't want to set a fixed width, follow these instructions to 'shrinkwrap' your container: [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center;`:

```
 #container {
 height: 410px;
 min-height: 410px;
 min-width: 756px;
 width: 756px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%; left: 50%;
 margin-top: -205px; /* Half the height */
 margin-left: -378px; /* Half the width */
 background: #e9e5e5;
 border: solid #dcdcdc 2px;
 outline: solid #c4c4c4 1px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(48, 50, 50, 0.28);
 **text-align: center;**
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
text-align:center;
float:center;
clear:center;
```

also works with left and right