# CSS: gradient header 100% width of screen fine unless page scrolls

Tags: javascript, css, header, scroll, gradient

### I have looked everywhere for this one and can only find solutions for background gradients.

This one has had me stumped, so...here goes.

I have a gradient header.  I want its width to be the width of the screen.  Which all works fine when resizing the window, except when scrolling to the side.  My gradient then turns to white space.

The content needs to stay at a large fixed width. In the HTML of my actual page the header is contained within a wrapper as well as another div. It be great if the solution was in HTML in CSS, but javascript and jquery will do if the former is impossible.

I have made a js fiddle showing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/WvHYM/18/

here's the html

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">&nbsp</div>
        <div id="content">This is the content</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and css it includes the gradient so it's a beast

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
}

#wrapper{
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #7d7e7d; /* Old browsers */ /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64, 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);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #7d7e7d), color-stop(100%, #0e0e0e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e', GradientType=1); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
#content {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
```

Here are some images of the problem.

[image: This is fine]

[image: Not cool!]

The answer would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Hmm. Looks like a problem with the actual image it's linked to. Here's a fiddle with the problem still there. http://jsfiddle.net/nt3vx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents?rq=1#3917059)

basically if you want a 100% width parent with dynamic fixed width children you need to set the parent element to display inline block and a width of auto (which is the default, meaning width can also just be left off completley.)

Important CSS

Parent

```
#wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Child

```
#content {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:20px;
    font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/WvHYM/27/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` only correspond to `<p>` tags. To resolve the issue, you'll need a `<div>` inside another `<div>`.

Try this:

```
<div id="header">

   <div id="header-gradient">

   //your content

   </div>

</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
#header {
   width: 100%;
}

#header-gradient:first-of-type {
   //style here
}

#header-gradient:last-of-type {
   //style here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment I updated my code now to have IDs instead. :) (so I could be more normal I guess) Though it's strange you say that, because it was working on fiddle with first-of-type last-of-type . . .

Comment: It's not that it won't work without the ids, but more that you need to style them separately and when they are nested like that you have to make them unique.

Comment: No sorry not yet.  I wish I could show you pictures of the problem I don't think I am describing it very well. The main problem is that when I make the window small and I scroll I see white space on the right-side of my header div. I want my header div to be 100% even when I scroll.  I don't know if this is possible with only css though.  My actual html and css isn't the jfiddle it just shows the same problem that I run into when I size my window down and scroll to the the right.

Comment: It is possible with only CSS.  Try setting your `html, body: 100%` in your stylesheet as well.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper"><div>&nbsp</div></div>
    <div>This is the content</div>
</body>
```

css

```
body{
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
div:first-of-type {
    height:75px;
    width:100%;
    background: #7d7e7d;
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #7d7e7d), color-stop(100%, #0e0e0e));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
    /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
div:last-of-type {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:20px;
    font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;
}
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/WvHYM/12/)

Comment: Yours works I tried copying it what am I missing? [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WvHYM/14/)

Comment: hi see your problem and i know how to solve that _maybe_ but i can't explain it correctly because my English is so bad.

Comment: @John pls visit [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/WvHYM/17/) maybe it help solve your problem