# CSS: I can't set width to "auto" always appear 100%

Tags: html, css

for some reason

the width of the div is 100% and if i set it to auto, nothing changes. tried `display: block;` and still nothing.

what I have in 
`index.html`

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>project x</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='box'>This is a box</div>
  <div class='box'>This is another box</div>
</body>
```

I enjoy cracking problems but this one crack me.

## Edit

I want the div to take the width of the words. I don't want it to be 100%.

Comment: what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: You forgot main part - what do you want?

Comment: @Rooster if want the width to be auto where it have the width of the words. its 100%. and I can't change it.

Comment: @Cthulhu I want the div to be auto, means it will take the width of the words not the whole screen. from want I see the width is 100% and I can't change to auto.

Comment: because for `div` width `auto` and `100%` have a same meaning! what do expect? and `block` is also useless for `div` because it is by default!

Comment: pull the `block` out or make it `display-block`

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer below. You're looking for a 'snap-to-content' solution which is most easily done by floating your parent containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `display: inline-block`

and add a class

`.clear { clear:both;}`

place it in between the boxes

so

http://jsfiddle.net/HpMSU/1/

Comment: why is this negative, it works for me in the fiddle unless you can be more clear what you want the boxes to do. I'm going off of you said you don't want them by each other.

Comment: probably it's because clear is completely unnecessary for inline-blocks. The empty div alredy separates them into different lines because it's block element. But this non-semantic div as a separator also doesn't look like a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

adding to Explosion Pills answer now that its clear what you want, this css should work.

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #555; 
    display: inline-block;        
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

Alternatively, you could place some `<br>` tags after each `<div>` block

Comment: display: inline-block is not necessary if float is set. Float itself is sufficient to make the element's width adjust to its content, and display property of floated element is just ignored (except for ancient IEs, where display:inline for floats prevented margin doubling bug).

Answer (score 1):

Width `display: block`, the elements will always use as much width as is available.  It seems like you want to use `display: inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/HpMSU/

Comment: but there is another box . the other box will be next the first and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

`width:auto` on a DIV expands it to fill it's parent, not to be sized by it's children.

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/nTWvr/

To size a DIV by it's content, there are a few methods: [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents)

Answer (score 1):

The following options can change the behavior of `width: auto` from using the available container width to so called [shrink-to-fit algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float):

1. Float:left/right
2. Position: absolute
3. Display: inline-block
4. Display: inline-table
5. Display: table
6. Display: table-cell

Assuming you need that the blocks to stay in the block formatting context of the normal flow (i.e. to go one after another vertically as usually, just have the width of their content), I suppose that in this case display: table will be the best solution.

Comment: I would say `inline-block` would be better.

Comment: inline-block changes the way the blocks are laid out, table doesn't. Also, inline-block makes the inter-tag whitespaces cause the gaps between elements, which is probably not what is wanted in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `width:auto;` is close to the same as setting `width:100%;` (the only real difference is that they handle margin and padding differently).

Also, `div` objects are by default block elements, so setting `display:block;` won't change their behavior.

---

You said you want the div to take up the width of the words. To do that you can either set `display:table-cell` (which is not very IE friendly) or you can float the div and it will snap to fit the contents inside.

```
.box { float:left; }
```

Make sure to properly clear your float after the div to avoid breaking the layout of contents below it.

```
.clear { clear:both; height:0px; } 

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question doesn't mention centering the element, but that's what I was looking for when I was directed here.

`display: inline-block` does its job in terms of width, but doesn't work if you also want to center the block. You can add `text-align: center` to the parent, but then you would have to override this property for all other elements inside you don't want centered.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto; // doesn't work with inline-block
}
```

```html
<div>Content</div>
```

To handle it properly just for this element you need `display: table`:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Content</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this result:

```
<head>
    <title>project x</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <span class='box'>This is a box</span>
    <span class='box'>This is another box</span>
</body>

.box {
    border: 1px solid #555; 
}
```

I just changed `div` to `span`! try to use proper HTML tags!

Comment: -1, I am guessing OP wants two boxes to hold content such as lists. A `span` is for stuff that's one line, not multi. The `div` is most likely the proper tag

Comment: Please don't guess! If he wants the tag not to expand he should consider span! not div because `div` is `block level` tag and `span` `inline` by its nature! That's what I got from question!

Comment: When have you heard of a BOX mean that? Never

Comment: Where this `box` word comes from? Have you ever read w3c html specifications? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/ I don't understand why some HTML developers try to invent new standards? Please find a meaning of `box` in HTML specifications and then explain meaning of box. Anyway I'm not going to continue this discussion with you! Just advise every one who's reading this message to read w3c html specifications first before starting to write any html code.