# min-width property doesn't work on Div, but works on Table tag

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a **div** in my page. I set it's **width** to **500px**. but sometimes it's content get space more than 500px. so I set it's **min-width** property to 500px.
it expect that is takes 500px by default and take longer according to it's content. but it takes whole of the page's width by default.

But if I replace the **Div** by a **Table**, it works correctly.
Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: could you have a JSFiddle?

Comment: you have to set width:auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the demo.
[Demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ufwQaL5p5grFJWMNNajh?p=preview)

You have to set in css like

```
   min-width: 200px;
   width: auto;
   float: left;
```

Comment: is the "float" attribute necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Normal block and things like tables, floats, inline blocks etc. use different algorithms of calculating width. For the normal block, the width is usually the available width of the container, and `min-width` is taken into account only if the container is narrower than it. For the latter things, the width algorithm is [shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float).

But there are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494527/2533215) to make the normal div behave like a table.