# How to center a set of html radio buttons in a fieldset with div

Tags: css, html, radio-button, fieldset

I have a set of radio buttons and labels.  The radio buttons precede the labels.  I would like to center the set of them within a field set.  I tried putting them in a div with display set to inline-block.  Almost works, but one label gets bumped down to the next line.

My understanding was that giving a div display: inline-block would make it [shrink-to-fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents), but I'm getting the unexpected behavior you can see here (code below):

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/TedVe/13/

Is my only hope to manually set margins and stuff?  Is there a way to understand why the div is shrinking just a bit too much??

Update...
If I remove the right margin from the label (which is there to add space before the next radio button) then it fits.  If, instead, I add margin-left to the button, I still have the problem.

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Test</legend>
    <div>
        <input class="radio-input" type="radio" name="test" value="yes" />
        <label class="radio-label">Yes</label>
        <input class="radio-input" type="radio" name="test" value="yes" />
        <label class="radio-label">No</label>
        <input class="radio-input" type="radio" name="test" value="yes" />
        <label class="radio-label">Maybe</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

```
.radio-label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
.radio-input {
    float: left;
}
fieldset {
    text-align: center;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this **remove** `float left` on your  `.radio-label` and `.radio-input` and now define

```
display inline-block
```

**As like this**

```
.radio-label {
   display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
.radio-input {
   display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TedVe/9/)**

Comment: Similar to @Bart's solution, except, maintains other styling such as the spacing and the vertical alignment between labels and buttons.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove all styles but text-align:center and you got it. No need to display: inline-block.

here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TedVe/8/

```
.radio-label {}
.radio-input {}
fieldset {
    text-align: center;
}
div {}
```

Comment: Simplest solution, but does not keep radio labels spaced apart with margin.  But gets to the point that all that is needed is to text-align the fieldset.

Nonetheless, would cause problems if I had other elements in the fieldset, such as a text input, that I did NOT want centered.

Comment: @abalter all that can be easily achieved. If you have any question on how to do that, just answer with that information. you can have a div wrapping the elements you want centered and applying a class. you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

```
use this following css.

.radio-label {
  margin-right: 3%;  
}

fieldset {
    text-align: center;
}
div {
     display:inline;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add width  for div then your problem may fixed

```
.radio-label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
.radio-input {
    float: left;
}
fieldset {
    text-align: center;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:50%
}
```