# how to make a div width end when its child elements end instead of taking all the available space?

Tags: html, css

this might be dumb but I'm kinda new to html and css.
I have..

```
 <div>
 <img src="#" alt="img">
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 </div>
```

css:

```
 div {
 background: blue;
 }
 div img {
 float: left;
 }
```

that makes the div background width take all the available space (to the end of the page), what I want is for the div blue background to end on its child elements ending.

I'm not exactly familiar with the block/inline. but applying inline to the div makes the background disappear, applying block does nothing. so what do I do to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make CSS Div Width Equal To Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `div` elements are displayed as *blocks*. By default blocks stretch to 100% of their container's width. As you've mentioned, setting them to display as `inline` will make them stretch to their content's width, however there is a mid-way point between `inline` and `block`: `inline-block`:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VXxHF/).

Answer (score 0):

use an inline-block

```
div {
 background: blue;
 display:inline-block
 }
div img {
 float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 div {
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 div img {
     float: left;
 }
```