# "overflow-y: scroll;" is hiding overflowing elements on the horizontal line

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

I have a `parent` div that contains an absolute positioned `child` div.

The `child` div is positioned outside the initial boundaries of `parent` div. It was rendering normally without any problems.

I added an `overflow-y: scroll;` to the `parent` div, and now the `child` element is hidden despite adding `overflow-x: visible;`.

**CSS**

```
#parent{
     position: relative;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     overflow-x: visible;
}
#child{
     position: absolute;
     left: -50px;
}
```

Also a [Fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajwnY/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well found this on stackoverflow, but you aren't going to be happy.

[CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue#6433475)

To put it short the answer says this

> If you are using `visible` for either `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` and
> something other than `visible` for the other. The `visible` value is
> interpreted as `auto`.

His answer goes more in depth talking about the W3 spec which explains this occurrence.

Pretty much your `overflow-x` can't be visible because it will turn to `auto`. (which part of that style hides the content that goes out of it.) if your `overflow-y` is anything different from it.

**EDIT:**

You could try this however as a workaround for that spec.

HTML

```css
/*Necessary styles for example*/
#parent{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#absolute-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
}
#child{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/*Below here is styles only for display purposes*/
body {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#absolute-child {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

#child{
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#child {
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id=parent>
    <div id=absolute-child>
        This is the child
    </div>
    <div id=child>
        This is the child
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BFLQr/

Give me a second to explain what I did.

**EDIT**

So first of all I basically had to move your parent div to be a child div of the parent div that is now there.  This is a little strange, but it's the only thing I could think of.  The now parent div has the "[shrink to fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents#451074)" style applied to it through `display: inline-block` this wraps it around it's child divs.

Since position `absolute` gets pushed out of the document flow this means your `absolute` position child does not affect the width or height of it's new "shrink to fit" parent.  The "shrink to fit" parent also has display `relative` this let's your `absolute` position div be positioned according to it. Also since the parent is now display `inline-block` in order to center it you must use text-align `center` on it's containing element. which means you also need to put text align `left` on your #parent or #child elements.

Hope this helped. :)

P.S. I edited the fiddle it had an unnecessary position relative on the #child element. I also added the text-align left to the new parent

Comment: so.. would these "rules" still apply in the case where i have a form, and its collapsed (height:0). But the contents were overflowing and affecting my body height. So i tried setting overflow-y to hidden and it automatically hid my x stuff too (even though I didn't even set overflow-x) --> so when i "expanded" my form.. it grew but no longer allowed my absolutely positioned labels to show outside the parents

Comment: @Carine Yes, since `overflow-y` was `hidden` even though `overflow-x` was `visible` it set it to `auto` behind the scenes and hid it. I would do something like this in your case if your using JavaScript http://jsbin.com/hohore/edit?html,css,js,output. The same could also be done with css transitions. I actually just learned about the `unset` value for css properties the other day and that's what I used in that jsbin to unset the `overflow-y` after the transition is over. It leaves the outer elements hidden until the end though so it's not the smoothest transition.

Comment: thanks. I had already ended up doing something before and after the transition...its crazy that they have this behavior tho...

Answer (score 1):

You can just nest another child container that holds the scrollable content which has `overflow: scroll` and keep your absolute div on the parent.

```css
.box1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
}

.box2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: dodgerblue;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: -25px;
  top: 0;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
     <p>item</p>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="box3">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tylorkolbeck/wmcu9jb1/2/