# Overflow-y: auto hides parts of elements that are positioned outside the div

Tags: html, css

I've created a very simple html structure, to represent a div with a button inside:

```
<div class="side-panel">
  <button>
    C
  </button>
</div>
```

in my app the wrapping div is a side-panel and the button's purpose is to control the toggle of the side panel. The button is located such that half of it is outside the side panel's div.

The problem is that when I set the `.side-panel` with `overflow-y:auto` the part of the button that's outside the div is hidden, and I cant figure out why nor how to make it visible while keeping the overflow y  Behavior.
here is a working snippet

```css
.side-panel {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 53px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px var(--grandma);
}
  button {
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    right: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="side-panel">
  <button>
    C
  </button>
</div>
```

with the problem

Comment: I suggest you use another element for the div with the overflow-y. and put the positioned absolute outside of it. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955465/overflow-y-scroll-is-hiding-overflowing-elements-on-the-horizontal-line)

Comment: What element is side-panel positioned relative to? I note that its height is defined by bottom: 0;

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.side-panel {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  width: 20vh;
  height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0px var(--grandma);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: -15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="side-panel">
    <button>
    C
  </button>
  </div>
</section>
```