# css how to make the div width just for the content

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Float</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="slideBar"></div>
        <div class="content">
            up
            <div class="div1">
                Hello
            </div>
            down
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my css style:

```
html, body {
margin:0px;
height:100%;
}
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.footer {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:green;
}
.mainContent {
    width:100%;
    height:60%;
}
.slideBar {
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
}
.content {
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    background-color:yellow;
}
    .content .div1 {
        border:2px solid black;
        margin-left:10px;
    }
```

This is the result:
[image]

#### My problem

the border of the `hello` word goes to all the width. but I need it just to be surround the text

Comment: I think if you don't define a width it will inherit the width from its parent. That's causing your problem

Comment: @TheChamp what should I do please? I don't know the width. maybe one word. maybe 1000 word. I can handle the overflow myself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Div Width Equal To Child Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div>` is a block-level element, so in order to get it to shrink around its content, you need to make it act like an inline element. Setting `display: inline-block;` on `.content .div1` will make it behave more or less like an inline element, and so it will fit to contents. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6wZhe/

However, what you might want to do is change out your `<div>` tag for a `<span>` tag, which is another multipurpose non-semantic container, except that is is an inline element, not a block-level element.

If you still want the linebreak after the `<div>` you can add a `<br />` element, or do it with floats.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block;`  to .content .div1    and in html add a `<br>`  above and below it:

http://jsfiddle.net/LYvft/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block` to it. http://jsfiddle.net/zhF4f/

Divs are "block elements"(`display:block`) which mean they take up 100% of their parent width. By setting inline-block, it only wraps the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can write display: inline-block; for div with class = div1 or replace your div to span.
Div is block element on default. If you use a text it is better to use span - default inline element.