# How to fit css textbox to content?

Tags: html, css

My CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/angel-beats-bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
    text-align:center;
}
.TextBOx {
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border: #solid 30px #000;
    background-color: rgba(105,100,100,0.8);
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0;
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Let this picture explains everything:
[image]

I want the border of that semi transparent textbox to autofit with that content. How do I do that ? I've tried `position:fixed;` but instead it screws up my page.

My complete script:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/angel-beats-bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: table;
    text-align:center;
}
.TextBox {
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border: #solid 30px #000;
    background-color: rgba(105,100,100,0.8);
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0;
    z-index:-1;
    display:block;
    text-align:center; 
    position:relative;
}
</style>
<body>
<img src="images/header.png" alt="OpenWrt Gratisan"><br>
<strong> 
<p>
<a href="status.php" title=""><font color="red">Status</font></a> | 
<a href="wget.php" title=""><font color="red">Wget WebUI</font></a> | 
<a href="putty.html" title=""><font color="red">Terminal</font></a> | 
<a href="wifi.php" title=""><font color="red">WIFI</font></a> | 
<a href="ch_pass.php" title=""><font color="red">Password</font></a> | 
<a href="profile.php" title=""><font color="red">Profile</font></a> | 
<a href="vpn.php" title=""><font color="red">Accounts</font></a> | 
<a href="ussd.php" title=""><font color="red">USSD</font></a> | 
<a href="sms_in.php" title=""><font color="red">Inbox SMS</font></a> | 
<a href="sms_send.php" title=""><font color="red">Send SMS</font></a> | 
</p>
<p>
<a href="vpn_log.php" title=""><font color="red">VPN log</font></a> | 
<a href="restart_log.php" title=""><font color="red">Restart Log</font></a> | 
<a href="wget_log.php" title=""><font color="red">Wget Log</font></a> | 
<a href="dial_log.php" title=""><font color="red">Dial Log</font></a> | 
<a href="about.php" title=""><font color="red">About</font></a>
</p>
</font></strong>
<br><br><br>
<div class="TextBox">';
MY CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>
.....
```

Comment: I want the border of that textbox to autofit with that content

Comment: div, perhaps I should say how to make the width of my semi transparent box to fit with the content of my page. Sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Div Width Equal To Child Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set it to `display: inline-block`.

Quote from this : [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents)

You will be able to center it by setting `text-align: center;` on the parent element.

(also check if you have any padding on that element)

PS : take the habit to post some code or a fiddle, it's easier to get the context of your question

Answer (score 0):

Just put your content in a DIV with width: 100%, then put that in the DIV.TextBox element (also watch for typos - you have a few).  This new DIV will fill 100% width of the parent element.

```
<div class="TextBox">
    <div style="width: 100%; ">
        MY CONTENT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

In regards to centering, add text-align: center to the .TextBox class.  There are other ways to center divs as well, such as margin: 0, auto ... but in your case stick with text-align: center.

```
.TextBox{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: How would a <div> play the role of a textbox? I mean how we edit the text?

Comment: I don't believe it would, the user just used "Textbox" as a class name... probably should have changed that