# Why isn't parent div width stretching to width of child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w9k2sz52/

```
#content {
    background: #ff0000;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.container-fluid {
    min-width: 2000px;
}

<div id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>Some title here</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the width of #content not stretching to be 2000px instead of being the width of the viewport? What do I need to do to make content stretch so that no matter what min-width is set on container-fluid #content will always stretch to fit it

Comment: One way is to set `#content`'s display to inline-block.

Comment: Was just writing that, here is the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9k2sz52/2/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Div Width Equal To Child Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents)

Comment: Inline-block is good, or also flex.

Comment: @Ruddy He wants to to fit the width of the child if the child is bigger than X amount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `#content` to `inline-block`, and then set `min-width` to `100%`.  Note that setting `width` to `100%` won't have the desired affect.

```
#content {
    background: #ff0000;
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `min-width` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a float will make the parent element the same width as the child:

```
#content {
    background: #ff0000;
    min-height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#content {
    background: #ff0000;
    min-height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
width:auto;
```

This should mean it stretches to the width of its contents.

EDIT:

> The min-width property in CSS is used to set the minimum width of a specified element. The min-width property always overrides the width property whether followed before or after width in your declaration. Authors may use any of the length values as long as they are a positive value.

You need to set a max-width or width with it. Say you had a width of 80% and a min width of 400px, it will be no smaller then 400px even if 80% of the page is 200px.

You could give the content a min width forcing the div to be auto and be no smaller then the content.

Answer (score 0):

Could #content determine the width, while .container-fluid expands to fill it? Instead of the other way around.

```
#content {
    background: #ff0000;
    min-height: 200px;
    width:2000px;
}
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding

```
position:absolute
```

to your CSS declaration for #content, you force the CSS interpreter to check what elements are inside #content, therefore achieving desired effect.

The problem with absolute positionning is that it remove the element from the natural workflow of the document. Therefore, you are better wrapping the element unto which you want to apply absolute positionning inside another element. This one will stay in the natural workflow of the DOM.

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7Ls47d83/4/

Google "CSS box model" for more interesting articles and post about this, or [this article](http://www.impressivewebs.com/absolute-position-css/).