# How to make flex div take only the needed space?

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I make a flex div to take only the space needed?
It is taking all available space.

I want to have lined up divs, wrapping when it needs. Problem is that the flex container takes more space than it actually needs.

Here’s an example http://cssdeck.com/labs/wvhe64ot

```css
#outer {
    border: 5px solid green;
    width: 400px;
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px dashed black;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
Dashed border should be close to the small divs
<div id="outer">
  <div id="container">
    <div>Lipsum</div>
    <div>Lipsum</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
   </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Make Div Width Equal To Child Contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents).

Comment: Problem with display: inline is that I also need wrapping. Same applies to width: -webkit-max-content or intrinsic.

Answer (score 66):

You might be looking for the `display: inline-flex` property. It treats its children just like the `display: flex` property, except it itself does not automatically grow.

Comment: Only works if there's no wrapping... I wanted wrap *and* parent div taking the smaller space possible. I'm thinking it can't be done with CSS because maybe the idea is: if there's wrapping/break, it's because the div wanted more than 100% of space, so even though width is reduced by breaking the elements continuity rearranging some childs in another row, conceptually it took more space than it could initially contain. So the width is considered to be 100%, making impossible to the parent div take only the needed space (same width of the largest "row" of childs).

Comment: It seems like you are right. I had a similar issue myself, and thought I would leave what worked for me. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work in your case!

Comment: Perfect. Helped me a lot today.

Answer (score 12):

What helped me was setting this for column-directed elements:

```
align-items: flex-start
display: flex
flex-direction: column
```

or this for row-directed-elements:

```
display: flex    
justify-content: flex-start
```

Answer (score 8):

set flex-shrink: 0 on div that you what to take at least required space

Answer (score 1):

You can put `flex-grow: 0` on the flex-items:

```
#container div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    flex-grow: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex
}

/* child you want to grow as needed */
.child {
  flex: none
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).