# Have a div match the contents width in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the html set up below. Inside `inner_container` there can be content that can have a width of `500px` to `50000px`. How might I set up the style so that `inner_container` matches the exact width of the contents width?

```html
<div id="main_container" class="main">
  <div id="scrollable_container" style="overflow: scroll; width: 9000px; height: 700px">
    <div class="inner_container" style="width: 12000px">
      <!-- Content here can be any widths... from small to reall large -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `width: 100%` on the content container

Comment: This is valid for setting the child to the width of the parent but it doesnt work the other way around. The OP is looking for a way to set the parents width dynamically based on the child's width. I would think the best method is to use a script if the content is truly dynamic. However, there appears to be a similar post on SO here which utilizes CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents

Answer (score 2):

In your stylesheet, set its `display` to `inline-block`.

```
.inner_container{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[More information on the `display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 2):

first for a better practice, separate your html from styling.

in html file:

```
<div id="main_container" class="main">
    <div id="scrollable_container">
        <div class="inner_container">
            <!-- Content here can be any widths... from small to reall large -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your css file

```
#main_container {
    float: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
#scrollable_container {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 700px;
    float: none !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
.inner_container {
    float: none !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:2px solid #ccc; /* So you can notice the difference*/
}
```

the `!important` are just in case (overwrite). And the `overflow:hidden;` is to make sure that the `inner_container` stays surrounding its content even if the contents are floated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
.inner_container { 
    display:inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```