# What is the difference between width:auto and max-width:fit-content?

Tags: css

I have a div on which

```
max-width: fit-content;
width: auto;
```

is applied, Now when I am removing any of the properties I do not see any changes. So unable to figure what is the specific difference between the two properties. I tried reading around fit-content but couldn't understand.

Comment: width:auto is useless because the default value is already auto. For the max-width, we need more context (HTML/CSS) because it depends on each case

Comment: That doesn't make it useless though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704073/what-is-the-difference-between-css-fit-content-and-max-content

Comment: @ChloeDev how that question is related to `width:auto`?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `display:block` element, using `max-width: fit-content` will make a difference.

Works on Firefox with prefix. [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_max-width_fit-content)

```css
.a {
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;
  max-width: fit-content;
  width: auto;
  background: pink;
}

.b {
  /* max-width: fit-content; */
  width: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor </div>
<div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor </div>

<!-- there is no difference if we are using inline or inline-block elements -->
<span class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor </span>
<span class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor </span>
```

Comment: *What is the difference between width:auto and max-width:fix-content?* <-- Note the **max-width** ... then *Now when I am removing any of the properties I do not see any changes* <-- Note the **any changes**. So I am not sure how this is answering the quesiton.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't understand the "I do not see any changes". When you remove the `max-width: fit-content;` you can see the difference.

Comment: Read the question again, the OP is *not seeing any changes* when using both of them and is asking *why*. You are actually showing the opposite so you are not answering his question of why both behave the same.

Comment: you are still showing a *difference* .. anyway, the question cannot be answered if we don't have more HTML/CSS because there is no generic answer and it's based on the other properties.

Comment: @VXp firefox support added