# Can a div take the dimensions of its absolutely positioned children?

Tags: css

There are some posts such [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents) that say you can set

```
display: inline-block
```

to the parent, but this did nothing useful for me.  The dimensions were then 0px by 0px.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id='si'>
  <p id='si_but' class='si_match blue_but radius_all small_white'>SignIn</p>
  <p id='si_cov' class='si_match opaque_but radius_all small_dark'>SignIn</p>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#si{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.si_match{
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding:  0px 15px;  
  text-decoration:  none;
}
#si_but{
  cursor:  pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<p>` elements are **absolute** positioned which takes them out of the normal document flow and therefore the parent element `#si` doesn't *"see"* them.

I would recommend removing the `position: absolute;` from `.si_match` and converting them from a `<p>` to a `<button>`.

Comment: It's more semantic. You're providing the user with an element that would be considered a button, so why not use a `<button>` element? If you'd rather not use `<button>` then I'd use a `<div>` or `<span>` instead. `<button>` will be an `inline-block` element. `<span>` an `inline` element. And `<p>` or `<div>` will be `block` elements and will want to take up the whole width of the parent element by default. An `inline` element will only take up the space it needs to, as will `inline-block`, but won't allow you to set dimensions on it where `inline-block` will.

Comment: That would work. You can stretch the button out vertically with `line-height` and/or `padding`. Horizontally you can let the text do most of the sizing for you and add some `padding` if you'd like or you could set a `width` or `min-width` on it as well. At this point you have a lot of options at your disposal.

Comment: Not rocket science at all. I've modified the code to your site in my browser and can verify the suggestions I've made do work. **P.S.** What is with the dual buttons?

Comment: It's not the CSS. Not to be mean or rude but it sounds like a loose foundation of knowledge in HTML/CSS that seems to be the culprit. There are options to add/change the style of the button without having to duplicate the element. Have you tried using the pseudo selector `:active` or some JS and applying a class to the button while you wait on the server and then removing the class once you get your response?