# Centering a wrapped flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a list that I would like to display on user's screen and allow him to reorder by drag'n'drop. This part is working.

I'm trying to display the list in several columns because there are sometimes too many options to display in only one column (the number of elements is varying).

I've used flexbox to do so, but I can't get my list to be centered, the flex container dimensions don't fit to its content.

```css
.params-order.overlay {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(30,30,30, 0.8);
    z-index: 999999;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.overlay-title {
  margin: 5% 5% 2%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}

.params-list {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 5%;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.params-list-item {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  cursor: move;
}

.params-list-item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
  top: 19%;
  height: 64%;
  width: 6px;
  border: 2px dotted #999;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay params-order">
  <h3 class="overlay-title">Overlay title</h3>
  <ul class="params-list">
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 1</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 2</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 3</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 4</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 5</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 6</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 7</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 8</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 9</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 10</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 11</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 12</li>
    <li class="params-list-item">Draggable 13</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've provided a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpEGqd

I've been able to make it by adding `self-align: stretch;` on the .params-list, but it makes it take all width, and I don't want this because I'm using the params-list to track the click and remove the overlay.

How can I fix the alignment?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your goal here. So the list items are already centered horizontally in your demo. You want them to wrap into separate columns and remain centered?

Comment: @Michael_B They are not centered on my browser (Chrome v43.0) I haven't even thought to try on another one. Here is the result I have : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/41/1444399173-problem.png

Comment: No, you are correct. That's the way it's looking when the column wraps. I was preparing an explanation for you. Try this: Add `height: 200px` and  `width: 100%` to `.params-list`.

Comment: The `width: 100%` do the job, but I don't want my list to take 100% when it doesn't need to, because I'm tracking the clicks outside of it to know when to remove the overlay. Isn't it possible to have the `.params-list` width to fit its content?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to display the list in several columns because there are sometimes too many options to display in only one column (the number of elements is varying).
>
> I've used flexbox to do so, but I can't get my list to be centered, the flex container dimensions don't fit to its content.

Your list is already centered horizontally as a single column. My understanding of your question is you want the list to remain centered when the column wraps.

The reason the list isn't wrapping is because you haven't defined a height for the container. Hence, the list will stack indefinitely in a single column because there's no height limit.

The second issue is the width. To center the nested flexbox within the container you need to define the frame of reference (i.e., specify the width of the container).

Try this:

```
.params-list {
    display: flex;
    margin: 5%;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 300px; /* NEW */
    width: 100%; /* NEW */
}
```

The column now wraps because there's a height limit, and the centering occurs along the full width of the container.

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbwpyV

---

UPDATE

Question comment:

> The `width: 100%` do the job, but I don't want my list to take 100% when it doesn't need to, because I'm tracking the clicks outside of it to know when to remove the overlay. Isn't it possible to have the `.params-list` width to fit its content?

Well, you're asking the nested flexbox with a `column` alignment to be horizontally centered in the container. In order to be centered, you need to define the `width` of the container, which would be `width: 100%`. If you confine `.params-list` to only the width of its content, you're still not defining the frame of reference for centering in the container. `.params-list` with multiple columns still needs to know: *Where should I center myself?*

You can test this in the demo by adding and removing the `width: 100%` in `.params-list`.

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbwpyV

However, if you change the `flex-direction` to `row`, then the flex items will stack and wrap in a row, and take up only the amount of width they need. In other words, you won't need to define `width`.

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjgBVv

Otherwise, you may want to consider alternative solutions:

- [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The fact is that I don't need to fix the height to have the column to wrap. This part works for me. 
I also would like to avoid having a fixed width (100%) for my list. Isn't there any way to do this?

Comment: The column wasn't wrapping in the demo. That's the only reason I addressed the `height` issue. I've updated my answer. If you have questions let me know.