# Css : Scale background color of a div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a `div` and I want to have the `background-color` of the `div` scaling after an hover so I did the following:

```
li { 
  background-size:  0 0;
  transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-size 2s ease-in;
  -web-kit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in
}
li:hover {
  background-size:  100% 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

I want to achieve a similar effect to the toolbars buttons hover on this website: http://www.materialup.com/posts/material-admin

Comment: I cannot find this toolbar button you speak of. Where exactly?

Comment: at the top right these little icons. you need to click launch website and then you will be able to hover these icons

Comment: a little typo on your CSS: `-web-kit` to `-webkit` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a `:before` element through css to get the desired result.

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xdbaoeu0/2/)**

```
li {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: white;
}

li:before {
  content: " ";
  transition: all 255ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 255ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 255ms ease-in;
  transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  opacity: 1;
}

li:hover:before {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure which toolbar button you mean, but if I understand your question correctly you want the background color wrapped around the listitem.

Adding `display: inline-table;` would normally get the job done.

Here's the fiddle with your example code: https://jsfiddle.net/5v5upekt/5/

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Sample HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Inline List</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS would be

```
.container{
      margin:auto;
      background-color:white;
      width:80%;
}


li:hover{
   -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
   transform:scale(1.1);
   opacity: 0.8;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
   cursor:pointer;
   }

li{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

You can find some hover and animation effects [here](http://james-star.com/answers/en/css3-hover-effect-transitions-transformations-and-animations/)

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ramkee/pcz7e75g/)

Please let me know is this what exactly you required.

Comment: I want to scale only the background color not the text who is with it because i know how to scale the whole thing but only the background is more difficult.