# Match child's width not working

Tags: html, css

I have a link (`a` element) with an image (`img` element) inside. I'm trying to make the parent element (`a` element) the same width as its child, which has a width of 75%.

I made the link to `display: inline-block`, just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917059/4861207) says to do, but it's not working. The parent element is still larger than its child. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```css
#img-link {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#img {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="img-link">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VROQLTe.jpg" id="img">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set 75% for `a` and 100% for `img`

```css
#img-link {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 75%;
}
#img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="img-link">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VROQLTe.jpg" id="img">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: inline-block;` from your `#img-link` rule.

Otherwise the image is going to be 75% of the `a` block.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
#img-link {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/sfbv7haw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

set width 100% and 75% on link

```
#img-link {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 75%;
}
#img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Don't Copy and Paste @Banzay Answer

Comment: I didn't copy paste was playing in jsfiddle and then posted.

Comment: @IvinRaj just because two answers match it doesn't mean he copied it. Grow up!

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple solutions:

1. The first one is to remove  `display: inline-block;` css from the anchor that wraps image. Then, it will resize according to the size of the image.

```css
#img-link {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#img {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="img-link">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VROQLTe.jpg" id="img">
</a>
```

2. Change the `width` of the image from 75% to 100%

   ```css
   #img-link {
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: lightblue;
   }
   #img {
     width: 100%;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <a href="#" id="img-link">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VROQLTe.jpg" id="img">
   </a>
   ```