# Last two divs are interfering: Text is disappearing into after section of previous div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having trouble trying to get the last two divs to work together nicely when trying to create responsive code. The divers of "product_conclusion" and "custom_footer" keep making "ca_text disappear part way.
I have been trying adjusting the pixels but it breaks too often so I tried the calc function. Either I'm doing it wrong or it is the wrong approach.
New to html5 and css3.

https://www.changedwards.com/feedback/coding-page-long-copy/text-code-5/

Comment: You're hardcoding the height which won't work with Responsive Design. Remove the hardcoded heights and then google "clearfix"  - `clearfix` will address the height issue and you won't have to worry about overlaps.

Comment: Because you're new to HTML/CSS3 - the reason you need to define your heights are because of elements with `float` - These will remove the element from the "DOM flow" which causes the parents to "collapse".

Comment: I got use to putting floats with heights thinking it would always expand properly. I guess not. Thank for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

I added comments, but here's the fix:

Remove `height` from:

- `.product_conclusion`
- `.conclusion_about`

Add `clearfix` to `.conclusion_about`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found that you determine div product_conclusion's height and use `display:block`

**Your problem is this:**

> 1. Your parent's `<div>`, in this case is `<div class="product_conclusion">`'s height did not respond its child's height.

**To solve this problem:**

> 1. Simply add `display:inline-block` or `display:table` on `<div class="conclusion_about">`
> 2. Remove all `height: n-px` on  your CSS, that will make your div can't expand more than that, or maybe you want to use `min-height:n-px` instead (Documentation source below)
> 3. Remove this CSS below (Because again, you don't want to determine the height) and your bottom will block the ca-text class of product_conclusion

```
//Try removing this
@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
    .product_conclusion {
        height: calc(100% - 30px);
    }
    .product_conclusion:after {
    height: 150px;
    bottom: -145px;
    }
}
```

**This is my CSS source code**

```
<style>
/*PRODUCT CONCLUSION*/
.product_conclusion p {
   margin: 0;
}
.product_conclusion {
   background-image: url(https://www.changedwards.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/white-brick-15.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
   //height: 800px; //Removed
}
.product_conclusion:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 240px;
    top: -239px;
    background-image: url(https://www.changedwards.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/white-brick-15_bottom-e1529272154540.png);
}
.product_conclusion:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 240px;
    bottom: -235px;
    background-image: url(https://www.changedwards.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/white-brick-15_top.png);
}
.conclusion_wrap{
    width: 100%;
}
.conclusion_about{
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    //height: 672px; //Removed
    display: inline-block; //NEW CODE or display:table;
}
.ca_text{
    width:63%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 3%;
}
.ca_picture{
    width:37%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 3%;
}
.ca_picture img{
    float: 0 auto;
}
.ca_text button {
  margin-top: 25px; 
  width: 150px;   
  font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
}
#instagram {
   background-color: #bc2a8d;
}
#facebook {
   background-color: #4F81BD;
}
#ca_picture_media {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
    .product_conclusion {
        //height: calc(100% - 30px); //Remove
    }
    .product_conclusion:after {
    //height: 150px; //Remove
    //bottom: -145px; //Remove
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .ca_picture{
        display: none;
    }
    #ca_picture_media {
      display: block;
        float: right;
        width: 35%;
    padding: 0 0 15px 15px;
    }
    .ca_text{
      width:100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .ca_text, .ca_picutre {
      width:100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
/*PRODUCT CONCLUSION END*/
</style>
```

**Solution Source:**

> 1. Div parent not responding to child's height:     [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents)
> 2. min-height CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for the help. It was taking me days trying to figure it out. Lifesaver! :)

Comment: Sure no problem, glad I could help :)

Please do mark this as an answer if this answer solved your question, thank you.

Comment: Turn out that `display:table` could help you too :) I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove anything from your code. Just add `clear:both;` property in `custom_footer` class.