# How to make a dynamic text responsive to the container size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make sure that the div container holds the text inside it without leaking any text outside. How can I make it responsive to grow or shrink the container size depending upon the dynamic text?

```css
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 15px;
  background-color: #0074d9;
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* left and right margin of flex elements inside this element container */
  margin-left: 5px;
  animation: roll 3s infinite;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  opacity: .5;
}

@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <p>Welcome!</p>
  <p>${user_name}</p>
  <p>${user_email}</p>
  <p>${user_contact} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share a visual example of what effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Geuis ! the user_name variable could be anything assume it is "rory mcCrossan" but when displaying the name it doesnot fit inside the container the text goes out of the box/container! my question is how to make the box/container grow or shrink depending upon the dynamic text!

Comment: because you setted a fixed width (120px), try without setting a width

Comment: Possible duplicate. Think you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your problem here is that the text is wrapping because you gave its parent container a set width of 120px. If you A) ditch the width or B) give it a `min-width` of 120px, you will get it to resize to accommodate longer names.

```css
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #0074d9;
  min-width: 120px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  animation: roll 3s infinite;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  opacity: .5;
}

@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <p>Welcome!</p>
  <p>Someguy Longlastname</p>
  <p>${user_email}</p>
  <p>${user_contact} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

faize
check this https://jsfiddle.net/kdrbh1Lw/10/
add this css rules to element class.

- **flex-wrap: wrap**
  **height: auto**
  **width: max-content**

when dynamically adding new data element container should expand both vertically and horizontally.

```css
.element {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-indent: 15px;
    background-color: #0074d9;
    height: auto;
    width: max-content;
    margin-right: 5px; 
    margin-left: 5px;
    animation: roll 3s infinite;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    opacity: .5;
  }

  @keyframes roll {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="element">
  <p>welcome</p>
  <p>${user_name}</p>
  <p>${user_email}</p>
  <p>${user_contact}</p>
    <p>${new_data}</p>
    <p>long long long long long long text</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code works fine if the width is also set to auto! like susggested by calvin and super dj thanks for the help! appreciate everyone for helping me out on this!!

Comment: @faize you can set width to max-content. then it expand horizontally too.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following. Using `min-width` you can specify a width it should definitely have but it can grow as much as it wants. If you don't like that you could also set a `max-width`.

```css
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px; /* gives equal spacing around */
  background-color: #0074d9;
  min-width: 120px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* left and right margin of flex elements inside this element container */
  margin-left: 5px;
  animation: roll 3s infinite;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  opacity: .5;
}

.element p {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.element p:last-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <p>Welcome!</p>
  <p>${user_name}</p>
  <p>${user_email}</p>
  <p>${user_contact} </p>
  <p>rory mcCrossan</p>
</div>
```