# Resize dynamically div by text size

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to resize the size of a div according to the width of the text, avoiding this wasted space, leaving the div compressed.
Example:

[Default size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOz9N.png)

The div should receive a cut such as:

[Desired size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf9Uo.png)

Example code:

```css
.linhaCodigo{
  background: #C0C0C0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo2">
              <h3>Cap 2 - Title</h3>
              <p align="left"><h4 align="left"><b>Title 2:</b></h4>
                textexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
              </p>
              <div class="linhaCodigo"> print("I like it!")<br>
                <b>Outup:</b><br>
                I like it!
              </div><br>
            </div>
```

Comment: add your HTML code

Comment: I added a enough example

Comment: This is an existing post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents

Comment: Thanks, i marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.myclassDiv{
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: this works, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome! can you tag is the correct anwser please?

Comment: I was just waiting for the 6 minutes haha.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this:

```
.linhaCodigo{
  background: #C0C0C0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```